# determine longest group of consecutive numbers

Tags: code-golf, number

**INPUT:**

- 10 random numbers
- each number is greater than 0 and less than 100
- list of numbers is presorted, lowest to highest
- the list will not contain any duplicate numbers

**CHALLENGE:**

Write a function that would take in the numbers, and return the count of the longest group of consecutive numbers.

**EXAMPLE OUTPUT:**

```
1 2 33 44 55 66 77 88 90 98 => return of the function would be 2
1 3 23 24 30 48 49 70 75 80 => return of the function would be 2
6 9 50 51 52 72 81 83 90 92 => return of the function would be 3
```

Answer (score 4):

### APL, <s>26</s> 21 characters

```
1+⌈/+/^\9 9⍴0,1=-2-/⎕
```

Here's the 26-character solution:

```
i←⎕⋄⌈/{1++/^\⍵↓1=-2-/i}¨⍳9
```

I used Dyalog APL as my interpreter, and `⎕IO` should be set to 0 for the 26-character version.

Example:

```
      1+⌈/+/^\9 9⍴0,1=-2-/⎕
⎕:
      6 7 51 51 53 51 54 55 56 55
3
```

[This answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4492/3284) explains most of what I in the 26-character solution, but I might have to write a new one up for the 21-character version.

Comment: It's not a golf challenge. Please visit this meta thread: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/456/373

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, 54

```
import List
f=maximum.map length.group.zipWith(-)[1..]
```

Comment: It's not a golf challenge. Please visit this meta thread: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/456/373

Comment: @user unknown: what challenge is it, then?

Comment: Ask Bromide. I didn't came up with it.

Comment: @user unknown: he was already asked; he declined to answer.  In the meantime, this is an algorithm question with no scoring criterion; there's no reason why I shouldn't restrict myself to short answers in *my* answer.  I'd upvote yours as well if you gave an explicit reason to.

Comment: Well - I don't want to discuss this with 10 different persons in the comments, so I started this thread on meta. Would it mind you, to repeat your argument there? I'm not interested in your particular answer here, but in the general case. See how others count their code size too. I guess a lot just repeat what they see, and believe it is a CG.

Answer (score 3):

### GolfScript, 23 characters

```
~]1\{.@-(!@*).@}*;]$)p;
```

Test cases:

```
"1 2 33 44 55 66 77 88 98"  --> 2
"1 3 23 24 30 48 49 70 80"  --> 2
"6 9 50 51 52 72 81 83 92"  --> 3
```

Comment: It's not a golf challenge. Please visit this meta thread: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/456/373

Comment: @user unknown: When arguing that against a GolfScript submission, you ought to make it clear that you're complaining about the explicit character count, not the language.

Comment: @JB: I thought it is clear from the meta thread.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
_JŒɠṀ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/e6@ikkwse7mz4//9/tJmOpY6pgY6poY6pkY65kY6FoY6FsY6lUSwA)

```
_J          Subtract [1,2,3…] from the input.
            This will turn a run like [48,49,50] into something like [45,45,45].
  Œɠ        Get group lengths. (“aaaabbc” → [4,2,1])
    Ṁ       Maximum.
```

Answer (score 2):

### Python

new:

```
def s(q):
    i = r = 1
    l = -1
    for n in q:
        if n == l + 1:
            i += 1
        elif i > r:
            r,i = i,1
        else:
            i=1
        l=n
 return i if i > r else r
```

old (buggy):

```
def s(q):
 i=r=1;l=-1
 for n in q:
  if n==l+1:i+=1
  elif i>r:r,i=i,1
  l=n
 return r
```

test case:

```
x = [1,2,3,50,56,58,60,61,90,100]
print x
print s(x)
>>> 3
```

edit: forgot the input numbers had to be in order. fixed
edit2: fixed a problem when all the numbers are a sequence, eg 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, and it returned just '1'
edit3: oops, didn't realize it wasn't code golf.

Comment: Try using `x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]` the result will be 1. Basically if the very last digit is part of a consecutive group it will return the wrong count.

Comment: @bromide thanks, fixed now

Comment: It's not a golf challenge. Please visit this meta thread: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/456/373

Answer (score 2):

## J, 23

```
>:>./(+*[)/\.(}.=>:&}:)
```

Sample use:

```
   >:>./(+*[)/\.(}.=>:&}:) 1 2 33 44 55 66 77 88 98
2
   >:>./(+*[)/\.(}.=>:&}:) 1 3 23 24 30 48 49 70 80
2
   >:>./(+*[)/\.(}.=>:&}:) 6 9 50 51 52 72 81 83 92
3
```

Answer (score 2):

### Python, 79 characters

```
f=lambda l:max(map(len,''.join(' x'[a-b==1]for a,b in zip(l[1:],l)).split()))+1
```

Comment: It's not a golf challenge. Please visit this meta thread: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/456/373

Comment: @userunknown: Indeed it's not.  However, it is such a trivial boring question that is much more fun to treat as code golf, and so I did so.

Answer (score 2):

### Mathematica, <s>50</s> 31 bytes

```
Max[Length/@Split[#,#2-#==1&]]&
```

This is an anonymous function. You can either give it a name, by assigning it to something, or you can just append `@{6, 9, 50, 51, 52, 72, 81, 83, 90, 92}` to use it straight away.

Here is how it works:

`#2-#==1&` is a nested anonymous function, which takes two arguments and returns `True` if the arguments are consecutive integers (and `False` for other integer pairs).

`Split` then partitions the resulting array into runs of elements, for which the above function returns `True`.

Now we map `Length` onto the result to figure out how many numbers each run contains, and select the maximum.

Thanks to David Carraher for eliminating large parts by using a test function in `Split`!

Comment: You can save 19 chars by eliminating `RotateLeft` and `Cases`: `Max[Length/@Split[#,#2-#==1&]]&`

Comment: @DavidCarraher Sweet! Thanks... I always forget that `Split` takes a test function.

Answer (score 1):

### Scheme/Racket

Here's a trivial answer in Scheme...

```
(define f
  (λ (l)
    (letrec ((g (λ (l M c p)
                  (cond ((null? l)
                         (max M c))
                        ((= (car l) (+ p 1))
                         (g (cdr l) M (+ c 1) (car l)))
                      (else (g (cdr l) (max M c) 1 (car l)))))))
      (g l 1 1 -2))))

(f '(1 2 33 44 55 66 77 88 98)) ;=> 2
(f '(1 3 23 24 30 48 49 70 80)) ;=> 2
(f '(6 9 50 51 52 72 81 83 92)) ;=> 3
```

where

- `l` is the `l`ist
- `M` is the `M`aximum consecutive number count found so far
- `c` is the `c`urrent consecutive number count
- `p` is the `p`revious number in the list

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby

I'm generally not that great at knowing more efficient methods. Might be some ruby standard lib things I'm missing.

```
def consec_count(arr)
  tg = 1
  cg = 1
  l = arr[0]
  arr.each do |v|
    if l + 1 == v
      cg += 1
      tg = cg if tg < cg
    else
      cg = 1
    end
    l = v
  end
  tg
end
```

Comment: It's not a golf challenge. Please visit this meta thread: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/456/373

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (80 <strike>93</strike> <strike>107</strike>)

```
for(n=prompt(c=m=1).split(' '),i=9;i;m=++c>m?c:m)c*=!(--n[i]-n[--i])|0;alert(m);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QqfY4/3/

**Edit 1**: Replaced `a` with `n[i]` and `b` with `n[i-1]`. Converted `Math.max` to ternary if.  Moved initialization statement into `for(`.

**Edit 2**: Reversed iteration direction to eliminate need for `i++` by changing to `--i` in second `n[--i]`.  Replaced `i++` with part of `if` body.  Changed condition to `i` to take advantage of ending at 0 = false.  Hard-code starting value of `9` due to spec `10 random numbers`.

Comment: It's not a golf challenge. Please visit this meta thread: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/456/373

Comment: I am seeing this more, I don't think Its a problem. We are learning how to program.

Answer (score 1):

### Python, 87 characters

Recursive solution:

```
def s(l):
 n=1
 while n<len(l)and l[n]-l[0]==n:n+=1
 return max(n,s(l[n:])if l else 0)
```

Testing:

```
>>> s([1, 2, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 98])
2
>>> s([1, 3, 23, 24, 30, 48, 49, 70, 80])
2
>>> s([6, 9, 50, 51, 52, 72, 81, 83, 92])
3
```

Comment: It's not a golf challenge. Please visit this meta thread: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/456/373

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't edit code, I'll redefine the Scheme answer (Racket or not, portable and easier to read). Variables have descriptive names and there is only one recursion of the list while being error free (i think). Who cares about characters when you got efficiency?

```
(define (count-consecutive lst)
  (call-with-current-continuation
    (lambda (return)
      (define (test n)
        (unless (integer? n)
          (return (error "Not integer: " n))))
      (define (g best) (f best n (cdr lst)))
      (let ([prev (car lst)] [count 0]) (test prev)
        (let f ([best 0] [prev prev]
                [lst (cdr lst)])
          (if (null? lst) best
              (let ([n (car lst)]) (test n)
                (if (= (- n prev) 1)
                    (let ([count (+ count 1)])
                      (if (> count best) (g count)
                          (g best)))
                    (let ([count 0])
                      (g best))))))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

### Scala

```
def maxconsec(ln:List[Int]):Int=
{
    var (max,current,last)=(1,1,-1)
    for(n<-ln)
    {
        if(n==last+1)
        {
            current+=1;
            if(current>max)max=current
        }
        else
        {
            current=1
        }
        last=n
    }
    return max
}
```

I think this is O(n); is it possible to be more efficient? Can the OP elaborate on how efficiency is being measured here?

Usage: (you can test it on [simplyscala.com](http://www.simplyscala.com))

```
maxconsec(List(6,9,50,51,52,72,81,83,90,92))
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python

```
def s(n):
l=0
t=1
for i in range(0,9):
    if n[i]+1==n[i+1]:
        t+=1
    else:
        if l<t:
            l=t
        t=1
return l
```

Comment: It's not a golf challenge. Please visit this meta thread: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/456/373

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 34 bytes

```r
u=rle(1:99%in%scan());max(u$l*u$v)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jc5bCoJAAIXh91bxQwra01ydmcL2YqYU2AjmVLu3ywJCOM/f@adli0ShNcZgLVWFc3hPEARPfWTq5jRFxp750tGn2M7XMfIc03Dm1KE2X0KjPjNogfGYgBM4ixdriYqAFViJVTiFl3j9q1BrCL2kehq6Qu5DyK8xv7dNLMrycGteRcqGXcoe5fLnY3kD)

This is a copy-paste of [Micky T's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/168438/80010) to [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/168427/80010). Upvote him!

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>7</s> 6 bytes

```
∞-γ€gZ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//Ucc83XObHzWtSY/6/z/aTEfBUkfB1ACIDYHYSEfBHIgtgGwLY6AUUNzSKBYA)

Thanks to @Kevin Cruijssen for -1 byte

Code:

```
∞       push endless list [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...]
-       subtract that from input
γ       group by equal elements
€g      push lengths of each group
Z       push max length
        implicitly print top of stack
```

Comment: [6 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//Ucc83XObHzWtST@84P//aDMdBUsdBVMDIDYEYiMdBXMgtgCyLYyB2BSIzWMB) (`∞` instead of `TL`). PS: `M` is the max number on the entire stack, whereas `à` and `Z` are the max number in the list (where `à` pops the list itself; and `Z` does not pop the list).

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 73 bytes

```python
def f(l):s=[n-i for i,n in enumerate(l)];return max(s.count(i)for i in s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7BDoIwDIbvPkWPLKkGGWND45MQDkRHXKKDjJHo088f5SCHJk3/72s7vuN98DKlm@2pzx7iNF0av3fUD4Ece3KerJ@fNnTRIm7PwcY5eHp2r2w6XIfZx8yJL72wk0hjcJj1WXNkKpikZCpLJqWYqopJayZjmOocZVohdv8C4GIpCBJACbCsIaHXWGDyjYB1CBVCBVfhmkYZ9EauFzY8ButTWAsBH0EB/QPTBw)

This works by subtracting the index from each number in the list and finding the greatest frequency in the list.

Comment: -6 bytes by using `max(map(s.count,s)`. [TIO](https://tio.run/##VY7BCsIwEETvfsUeE1ilNkmbKn5J6aFoggWbljQF/fo4Yg96GFh25s3u/Er3Kaicb86TFw95Wi5t2A/kp0gDBxoCubCOLvbJwe7O0aU1Bhr7pxj7WSyH67SGxIuUeY5DSMKL9shUMinFpDWTMUxVxVTXTNYyNQVkOyl3vwDC5UcAFAIaQd0AwlyjwBZ/AOpgGpgGrMG1GrKYrdou/OWx2J5CLQB8BATpbzC/AQ). Could save another by using Python 2 and `print` instead of `return`

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 7 bytes

```
▲mLgz-N
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9G0Tbk@6VW6fv///48207HUMTXQMTXUMTXSMTfSsTDUsTDWsTTQsTSKBQA)

#### Explanation

```
▲mLgz-N
    z N  zip input and infinite list [1..]
      -  with '-'
   g     group adjacent equal values
 mL      map length
▲        maximum
```

Answer (score 0):

### Java

```
public static int getConsecutiveCount(int[] A) {
    int r = 1, t = 1;
    boolean c = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        if (i + 1 < A.length) {
            if (A[i + 1] - A[i] == 1) {
                    t++;
                    c = true;
            } else {
                c = false;
            }
        } else {
            c = false;
        }
        if (t > r && !c) {
            r = t;
            t = 1;
        }
    }
    return r;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Just for fun, CJam, 24 bytes

```
l~]M\{:H(=+H}*;0a/:,$W=)
```

I know this is not valid as the language did not exist at the time of asking the question, but I thought I will give it a try.

**How it works:**

```
l~]M\                     "Read the input, convert to array, put an empty array M before it";
     {      }*            "For each pair of the array, run the code block";
      :H(                 "Assign the second number from the pair to H and decrement it";
         =+               "Check if it is equal to previous number and put result in M";
           H              "Put back the second number so as to be used in next iteration":
              ;0a         "Drop the trailing last number and put [0] on stack";
                 /        "Split M on [0]";
                  :,      "For each split element, replace it with its length";
                    $W=   "Sort the final array and take its last element";
                       )  "Increment this highest element from the array";
```

[Try it online here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

Answer (score 0):

## Perl

```
my @o = (1,4,4,6,7,45,46,47,48,98);

sub r{
    $c=1;
    $l=pop@_;
    $m=1;
    while($n=pop@_){
        if($l-$n==1){++$c;$m=$c if $c>$m}
        else{$c=1}
        $l=$n
    }   
    $m  
}

print "MAX: " . r(@o);
```

**Output:**
MAX: 4

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 9 bytes

```
äa è_¥1ÃÄ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn///CSRIXDK@IPLTU83Hy45f//aDMdBUsdBVMDIDYEYiMdBXMgtgCyLYyBUkaxAA)

Comment: `è¥1 ` saves a byte. However, this approach will fail if the input contains more than 1 run of consecutive numbers.

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 55 bytes

```julia
a->((d=diff(a))[d.!=1]=x=0;maximum(x=(x+y)y for y=d)+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY5BasMwAATvecX0JhG1SLJsSy3KR4wPAsWgErtBJGC/3nVKYQ/Dzh72@3krqdsnInt6vwiRYy7TJJKUQ/54i2aMa9Rfc1rL/JzFGsV63uTG9FPZYpZnI/cXp1opC2IwNNgjjkbjPC7Qa/oWr8fhc1QMHYFW0xpaS2/xBt8QNMH@L4LCKKyiUThFp/CK/mXcX3cYM8oT3GtZHrdFHH9rlfJ0XfL@Cw)

Going for \$ O(n) \$,

#### 82 bytes

```julia
a->(l=m=0;i=1;while i<length(a);a[i]==a[i+1]-1 ? l+=1 : l=1;l>m&&(m=l);i+=1;end;m)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY7BasMwGIPvfQqdik1d8O84iV3P3YMEHwxLVpc/3ggtffzMGwOhgz6BdH9yycO@IGLP56vguEYdSqTwuhWeUd54rp@Pm8gy5KmkGJufKJ0J7@BTJFzArc3X9XgUa2QZSkvDXD/CKvfla0PeNpQKMRE6mCaLTsM6WI9RY@zhdJouSWEa4NFr9ITeYDRwBNfBa3jz3/AKpGAUOgWrMCg4hfGX2L@sEUryAHxvpT64ikW0fSkP7dD@Aw)

which ungolfed is:

```julia
function f(a)
    l = m = 0
    i = 1
    while i < length(a)
        a[i] == a[i+1]-1 ? l+=1 : l=1
        if l > m
          m = l
        end
        i += 1
    end
    return m
end
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-h`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 9 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
í- ò¦ mÊn
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWg&code=7S0g8qYgbcpu&input=WzYgOSA1MCA1MSA1MiA3MiA4MSA4MyA5MCA5Ml0)

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 45 bytes

```
[ [ - -1 = ] monotonic-split longest length ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY@7asMwAEX3fMX5AQdZD0tuKXQLWbqUTiGDMaor4kiupA6l9Ntd46Fw4Q6HC@e@D2NNeX17Pb@cHrgP9YObz9HPlGUOtYY4He8ppppiGCn@88vH0ReW7Gv9XnKIlcfD4YcWiVJojTF0HdbiHL2gd/zuXCG3aJRAO3SPFViDEzvv6DEC02IkVuJanNr3cuPrhQsNTcsTV/6Fml2SOcXJl619nLYD17Xm8MyxMM5@yOsf)

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 30 bytes

```r
x=scan();max(rle(x-seq(!x))$l)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY3BCsIwEETvfsUKHrKwQm2SJkX6MSVEFGulrUKK@O1xCgXpYWCZnTcz5nCN4R7H5vLuw@v27NXMnym0/d/gOadmsRSfH21SYxdVOk5xUPvEfOg4f3driwrqJFQKaS1kjJC1QlUl5JyQ90J1AXnmLYBwuQiARsAgaGpAuB0KfLEBUIenxdOCtVhzkMft9bpQMucf)

Approach boringly copied from other answers, but different from (and slightly shorter than) [JayCe's earlier R answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/169761/95126).