# Count Consecutive Characters

Tags: code-golf, string, alphabet

Given a string containing only letters, output the length of the longest run of consecutive alphabetical letters the word contains, where order does not matter. An example algorithm may sort the word, remove duplicates, and then output the length of the longest run.

### Test Cases

```
watch -> 1
stars -> 3
antidisestablishmentarianism -> 3
backdoor -> 4
a -> 1
tutorials -> 4
```

For example, `antidisestablishmentarianism` contains the letters `abdehilmnstr`. The longest runs are `lmn` and `rst`, both of length 3.

### Notes

You may take all lowercase, all uppercase, or mixed-case letters as input, but the case cannot encode information about the word (i.e. you cannot make the first `n` characters capitalized where `n` is the length of the longest run).

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: @H.PWiz, I'm guessing that's a typo and it should be `rst` - uniquify, sort and get longest consecutive run. Can we take input as an array of characters?

Comment: @Shaggy yes, definitely, I didn't include it because I thought it was a default

Comment: Is 'a' adjacent to 'z' -- should 'zebra' score 2 or 3?

Comment: (...judging by your example algorithm I guess "no" and "2")

Comment: @JonathanAllan you are correct

Comment: Interestingly (or not), the only two words I've found that are scoring 7 are birds: `goldfinches` and `paroquets`. Another suggested test case: `propinquities`, which scores 8.

Comment: Also, `feedback` looks like the most straightforward way to get `abcdef`.

Answer (score 10):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>10 9 8 7</s>  6 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
OṬṣ0ZL
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9//4c41D3cuNojy@f//f2JeSWZKZnFqcUliUk5mcUZual5JYlFmYl5mcS4A)**

<sup>9 was using [Sok's method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/168433/53748): `ṢQẆẇƇØaṪL`</sup>

#### How?

```
OṬṣ0ZL - Link: list of (single-case) characters  e.g.  codegolf
O      - ordinal (vectorises)           [99,111,100,101,103,111,108,102]
 Ṭ     - untruth (1s at those indices)  [0,0,0,...,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1]
       -                                 ^         ^       ^         ^     ^
       -                   i.e. indices: 1        99     103       108   111
   0   - literal zero
  ṣ    - split at                       [[],[],[],...,[1,1,1,1,1],[],[],[],[1],[],[1]]
    Z  - transpose                      [[1,1,1],[1],[1],[1],[1]]
     L - length                         5
```

Answer (score 8):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>44</s> 43 bytes

Works on an array of lowercase characters.  Edit: changed it from testing True values to multiplying by the T/F for a byte.

```r
function(x,r=rle(letters%in%x))max(r$l*r$v)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY4xDsIwDEVnOEWHVklQFwRrDpO2qWrhJsh2S24fIgaEAhKe3/P7lGeb5y2MAjHo1JMl9Bq9iCfuIHTJmNUlTS2eqN1NnrVHzUJ8RxCtHk7GRfVKGWOaQzlrm/OxglgccQVdasgFgQnYF3hA4GX1oWjgAvD6dn@JgxtvU4xUBa5fgX8zZZNYgvg59fUoPwE)

Does a run length encoding on letters that are in the supplied characters then return the max value for the trues.

Comment: Was working on a similar rle solution using utf8ToInt but taking an array of string is much smarter. +1

Comment: @JayCe Started out the same way, but then realised that a letters %in% check took care of the sort, unique and diff steps in one swoop

Answer (score 7):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

-1 byte thanks to H.PWiz

```apl
≢⍉↑⊆⍨⎕a∊⍞
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY3NSsNQEIX3eYrZjUILFrtyl/5Ag20CTcT1JeaWYJobbm4RKd1JbKK36MKlgl35AiIUfJl5kTjq7pz5Ps6IIute3YpMLbpxJsoyjVvavaSKqqcTh7b3sqV6T7am6pmaiuwHU0Hbhuxby7iVLJLd9ejxGzdr7CADZEdz@ERq9ky@uMcaJQLZVzArnUOslkWWmAQKrRZaLCHNjQIBcpXHJlU5lApuEohFDiYpDaTGMfxpzaNUv2uOkuzhDNU10sMdSpFm/PDAWG8cvHSj4QQN9BwMI3cecjx10PUjb@SFYz4Npl44mY19hp7re@Hs3xi4w/NREMy59Z2jDrp4/DcSXUQBi9Pfof4P)

`⍞` inputs a string

`⎕a` is the uppercase English alphabet

`⎕a∊⍞` a boolean length-26 vector - which letters occur in the string?

`⊆⍨` form vectors of consecutive 1s

`≢⍉↑` mix into a matrix, transpose, and return its height - effectively, find the length of the longest vector of 1s

Comment: `⌈/≢¨` -> `≢⍉↑`

Answer (score 6):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 51 bytes

The case of the input string doesn't matter.

```javascript
s=>(g=_=>s&&1+g(s&=s*2))(Buffer(s).map(c=>s|=1<<c))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY69DoIwFEZ3n4IwkFYjBGWkDL6IuZQWqv0hvUUX3712wAXDfM538j3gBci9msPZukFEySKyjozszjosivo0EiwYHi@UktsipfAEaWlgJjwJH1a3Lac0cmfRaVFqNxJJ8jcEPuWUZlWV1YcNxAAeV3jdQrBBDQpFknqtcDLCJl2BVWj2Nj3w5@CcX3nz19x7EpbgUlv/3jTxCw)

#### How?

We first convert the input string into a bitmask of encountered letters with:

```javascript
Buffer(s).map(c => s |= 1 << c)
```

The bitwise shift is processed with an implicit modulo 32.

Example:

```
"feedback" --> 100001111110
               kjihgfedcba-
```

We then 'reduce' runs of consecutive 1's in the bitmask by repeatedly AND'ing it with a left-shifted copy of itself until all bits are cleared:

```
0100001111110 AND 1000011111100 --> 0000001111100
0000001111100 AND 0000011111000 --> 0000001111000
0000001111000 AND 0000011110000 --> 0000001110000
0000001110000 AND 0000011100000 --> 0000001100000
0000001100000 AND 0000011000000 --> 0000001000000
0000001000000 AND 0000010000000 --> 0000000000000
```

The number of consecutive letters in alphabetical order is the number of iterations of the above process. Hence the recursive function:

```javascript
g = _ => s && 1 + g(s &= s * 2)
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 41 bytes

```perl6
{max values bag .ords.sort.squish Z-0..*}
```

[Test it](https://tio.run/##TY9BTgMxDEX3OYVVVQjKNJRSdTMq4hCsQCw8SaARmWSInbao6snYcbEhaUBil/z//rc9mOjWYyIDu7VUrRD9J1yooA1sxmOPB9ihS4agwzeQIWqSFCJL@kiWtvA0X0g5O4059MCGGDbgrDf0/SX3BX6etYtm@ZJry4THTLRicOjhuuI3sMzea4i/8fk9TK0fEjcwNYfBKDYajgLAEpSlLqt79c9uYFLFc/hPnYjTuEdW26LeCmKMVJ53Aj1bbSlPw87lG3rjs2nRW@or0aF61yHvlH8rgbWBE4dMuXPL6gc)

### Expanded:

```perl6
{  # bare block lambda with implicit param $_

  max       # find the max
    values  # get the values from the following Bag (repeat counts)
      bag   # find the repeats

          .ords.sort.squish # get the unique ordinals (method call on $_)
        Z-                  # zip subtract with
          0 .. *            # Range starting with 0
}
```

Given `'stars'`, `.ords.sort.squish Z-0..*` would return `(97,113,113,113)`

Answer (score 6):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 35 bytes

```hs
f[]=0
f s=1+f[c|c<-s,elem(succ c)s]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcrBCsMgEATQe75ikR5amkJ7r18iOWw2iktWDa6hl/67tYdhGN5E1N2L9B7cYp9TALWve3D0pfdDZy8@XfUkArrp0sU688FG0cxGG1YdjbnxxurHXoU1Jp@HMGbWNHhF2rdS6v850s5WBoqaZUrIGSwclXODCyQ8IID0Hw)

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 50 bytes

```hs
f s=maximum$scanl(\x c->sum[x+1|elem c s])0['a'..]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcpBCsIwEAXQvacYQqGKWvQA9SK1i2makqEzackk2IV3j3Hx@Xze96irYy5lAe0FD5IsjVoMfH4fYO8vzTIc1@fXsROwoOPlMbTYdt1YuB/MB5P15mY0YdTaGBLNpK7uiUm9uFCFMJBK5QntOm9b/D9rUk5bRVYzngQpQA97pJCgAcEdFuDyAw)

Answer (score 5):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 9 bytes

```
le}#G.:S{
```

Input is assumed to be a lower case string. Try it out online [here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=le%7D%23G.%3AS%7B&input=%22stars%22&debug=0), or verify all the test cases at once [here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=le%7D%23G.%3AS%7B&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22watch%22%0A%22stars%22%0A%22antidisestablishmentarianism%22%0A%22backdoor%22%0A%22a%22%0A%22tutorials%22&debug=0).

```
le}#G.:S{Q   Q=eval(input()), G=lowercase alphabet. Trailing Q inferred.

        {Q   Deduplicate input string
       S     Sort it
     .:      Take all substrings (these are generated in length order)
  }#G        Filter out those that aren't found in the alphabet
le           Find the length of the last remaining element
```

Comment: Great method using the fact that the substrings are ordered by length!

Comment: It'll be much less efficient, but you can use `y` in place of `.:`.

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 10 bytes

```
2Y2imY'*X>
```

Input is in lowercase.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/3yjSKDM3Ul0rwu7/f/WS0pL8oszEnGJ1AA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##FcpLCoAwDATQvRcJuOwBXHkEF3Zn@oEGmxaaiMevcTEMwxtGrfOazjtiD@u5zf2Y8KLGAguI4hBrbEqJJNsOlaRwbiaEjYSNA8Y79T7@p0Uf7YZV4AM).

This uses a mix of [@Sundar's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/168431/36398) (old) and [@ngn's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/168430/36398) approaches.

#### Explanation

Consider input `'tutorial'` as an example.

```
2Y2   % Push predefind literal 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
      % STACK: 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
i     % Push input
      % STACK: 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'tutorials'
m     % Ismember: true for letters present in the input
      % STACK: [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]
Y'    % Run-length encoding
      % STACK: [1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0], [1 7 1 2 1 2 1 2 4 5]
*     % Multiply, element-wise
      % STACK: [1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 4 0]
X>    % Maximum. Implicitly display
      % STACK: 4
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 55 bytes

```python
f=lambda s:s and-~f({*s}&{chr(ord(c)+1)for c in s})or 0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYq7CsIwAEVn/YpMJvEBilvBIX1Ag31Ak@IgDrEltKBpSbpIqb8eE5fL4Zw7fqZuUGdr5eUl3s9WABMYIFR7@Eo0b82ymZtOo0G3qMG7E5aDBg3oFTALdni0Xhgv7vBGeJTCPYCMk4p5IAWnMWWJE2FGWZonhUuUFJTlvockusZlWf2/fnjNS9czBh/BejXqXk1IIoOx/QE)

---

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 58 bytes

```python
f=lambda s,c=99,r=0:c and max(r,f(s,c-1,-~r*(chr(c)in s)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY09C4MwGITn9le8W5ISoe2m4BA/wFA/wKR0KB3SiCjUKNGhXfrXbexy3N1zcNNn6UZzXtc2fKnh2SiYqQ59n9rwGGhQpoFBvbGlLXbAO1Hvaw9YdxZr0huYCSFrO1qYwaU7ujEZZ4gCEpLVYjOslDzhInVFlHORFWnpEGclF8XGIxZfkqqq/9tN5FVWjucCPYL9brK9WcCdk/UH)

---

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 63 bytes

```python
n=t=0
for c in input():n|=2**ord(c)
while n:n&=n/2;t+=1
print t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcJBCoMwEAXQfU4RXIjahTVLZQ6TakoG9Cckv5RC75728fKHMcG1BqHczTMVu1vFf35xGFd8xU1TKsewj@Yd9QwWK3rB7DbeZDG5KGjZWudBPbSGSv84tcYrgL6oh9ar@wE)

Comment: What about using python3 bytes as input: [`f=lambda s:s and-~f({*s}&{c+1for c in s})or 0`](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P802JzE3KSVRodiqWCExL0W3Lk2jWqu4Vq06WdswLb9IIVkhM0@huFYTyDT4DxIoBglEJ6mHO4Y4e6jrKCSpB4c4BgWDWY5@IZ4unsGuQBEnH89gD19XP6Ccp6OfZ7AvWIGTo7O3i79/EEQ1mAwJDfEHKvEJVo@14uIsKMrMK9FI0yjW1PwPAA)?

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

Saved 1 byte thanks to [Adnan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/34388/adnan): taking the contiguous substrings, then sorting by length (`Œ...é`) \$\to\$ using the powerset built-in instead (`æ`).

```
êæAÃθg
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V9TVmmvpKBrp6BkX/n/8KrDyxwPN5/bkf7ftvZ/eWJJcgZXcUliUTFXYl5JZkpmcSqQl5STWZyRm5oHFM9MzMsszuVKSkzOTsnPL@JK5CopLckHCucUAwA)

#### Also 6 bytes

Saved 2 bytes, again thanks to [Adnan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/34388/adnan): using `ASå` instead `êÇ¥Θ`, thus also removing the need to increment the maximum at the end. See [the revision history](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/168458/2) to compare the beviours of the two methods.

```
ASåγOà
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V9TVmmvpKBrp6BkX/nfMfjw0nOb/Q8v@G9b@788sSQ5g6u4JLGomCsxryQzJbM4FchLyskszshNzQOKZybmZRbnciUlJmen5OcXcSVylZSW5AOFc4oB)

#### How those works

I like challenges like this one which lead to a variety of different approaches.

```
êæAÃθg | Full program.
ê      | Push a sorted and without duplicates version of the input.
 æ     | Powerser.
  AÃ   | Keep those that also occur in the lowercase alphabet.
    θg | Take the length of the last one. θ and ` can be used interchangeably.
-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ASåγOà | Full program.
A      | Push the lowercase alphabet.
 S     | Listify it (i.e. convert it to a sequence of characters).
  å    | Replace each char in the alphabet by 1 if its in the input, else by 0.
   γ   | Split into chunks of equal adjacent elements.
    O  | Sum each part.
     à | Extract the maximum of this list. Again, à and Z can be used interchangeably.
```

Comment: The first program can be golfed to `êæAÃ\`g` and the second program can be golfed to `ASåγOZ`.

Comment: @Adnan Thanks, updated! I like the `ASå` trick.

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>58</s> 56 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to @gastropner*

Uses the same approach as [my Node.js answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/168434/58563). The case of the input string doesn't matter.

```c
m,i;f(char*s){for(i=0;*s?m|=1<<*s++:(i++,m&=m*2););s=i;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY3LDoIwFET3fsUNRtMCPlBXFvRbagtyI21Nb4kL9NuxCzHRZFZnTmbU6qrUOEerul7XUFLQ6NbtaTQ5ioapVvqU@NA4z7DaipTO5lkVZZlSlh0ZZllulpVJd1xwQRWK14g2gJFoGYdhBnD3ETQsWWj4TZLHFiBWDxlUm/AcNhsoJkhBevrA/QSlDaiR6lheOqTW1DZqKC2S@XcvUt20c/7DD9@N/6fQBxc3uvg2iVzMXuMb)

#### Commented

```c
m,                   // m = bitmask of encountered letters
i;                   // i = counter of max. consecutive letters
f(char *s) {         // f = function taking the input string s
  for(               // main loop:
    i = 0;           //   start with i = 0 and assume m = 0 on first call
                     //   (it is forced back to 0 when the program terminates)
    *s ?             //   if we haven't reached the end of the string:
      m |= 1 << *s++ //     update m by setting the appropriate bit for this character
                     //     (with implicit modulo 32) and advance the string pointer
    : (              //   else:
        i++,         //     increment i
        m &= m * 2   //     'reduce' runs of consecutive 1's in m by AND'ing it with a
      );             //     left-shifted copy of itself (e.g. 11101 & 111010 -> 11000;
                     //     11000 & 110000 -> 10000); we stop when m = 0
  );                 // end of for()
  s = i; }           // return i
```

Comment: Is it implementation specific that `1<<*s` wraps or is it standard behaviour?

Comment: @JonathanFrech I think that's officially undefined behavior. So it must be implementation specific.

Comment: Because interestingly enough it only appears to wrap when it is computed at runtime.  At compile time `1<<32` results in `0` and issues a data type size warning.

Comment: Actually, I doubt that the compiler would explicitly apply a 5-bit mask. Chances are that this is done at the CPU level.

Comment: @Arnauld [it is](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_285.html) (see the note: "[...] The count operand can be an immediate value or register CL. The count is masked to 5 bits, which limits the count range to 0 to 31.")

Comment: You can drop `m=` since `m` will be zero on first call, and reset to zero by the bit counting. Requires using `s` for implicit return. This shaves [another 2 bytes off](https://tio.run/##XY3LDoIwFET3fsUNRtMCPlBXFvRbagtyI21Nb4kL9NuxCzHRZFZnTmbU6qrUOEerul7XUFLQ6NbtaTQ5ioapVvqU@NA4z7DaipTO5lkVZZlSlh0ZZllulpVJd1xwQRWK14g2gJFoGYdhBnD3ETQsWWj4TZLHFiBWDxlUm/AcNhsoJkhBevrA/QSlDaiR6lheOqTW1DZqKC2S@XcvUt20c/7DD9@N/6fQBxc3uvg2iVzMXuMb "C (gcc) – Try It Online").

Comment: @gastropner Nice catch. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## TSQL (Microsoft SQL Server), 206 bytes

```
WITH C AS (SELECT 1p,SUBSTRING(@,1,1)c UNION ALL SELECT p+1,SUBSTRING(@,p+1,1)FROM C WHERE p<LEN(@)),R AS(SELECT c d,1r FROM C UNION ALL SELECT c,r+1FROM R JOIN c ON ASCII(d)+1=ASCII(c))SELECT MAX(r)FROM R
```

For input, use the following `DECLARE` statement before the code:

```
DECLARE @ varchar(200) = 'propinquities';
```

It is expected that input is all the same case (upper or lower doesn't matter, but mixed case would not work).

**Ungolfed:**

```
DECLARE @data varchar(200) = 'propinquities'

;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT
        1 as CharacterPosition,
        SUBSTRING(@data,1,1) as Character
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        CharacterPosition + 1,
        SUBSTRING(@data,CharacterPosition + 1,1)
    FROM
        CTE
    WHERE CharacterPosition < LEN(@data)
), Runs AS
(
    SELECT Character, 1 rc
    FROM CTE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT b.Character, rc + 1
    FROM Runs r
    JOIN CTE b ON ASCII(r.Character) + 1 = ASCII(b.Character)
)
SELECT max(rc)
from runs
```

**Explanation:**

Splits the string into a a row for each character (adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/27623321/1474939) in the `CTE` cte.

Then, finds runs of consecutive letters by converting to the ASCII code in the `Runs` cte.

Lastly, it picks the largest run and reports back in the select statement.

Comment: Good answer, very nice use of the CTE. Not sure if this would help or hurt your byte count, but the ["approved" method to get input in T-SQL is via a pre-created table](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5341/70172).

Comment: @BradC If I can take a table with each row as one character (sort of like a char array instead of a string), then it would help remove one CTE. If it still has to be one row, it's probably about the same as taking it as an input variable. Thanks for the idea though!

Answer (score 3):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://bitbucket.org/ngn/k), <s>17</s> 15 bytes

```
#1_{x^x^x+1}\-:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYzLDoIwFET3foWpLjTKotFV76cAyuVRaQpt0l4jhOCv19aEzOrMmYzOzMuEIMWBP5fpEXPha5GJQGI55vPXCbmfoLIaTpVENcAEM7hzue4oZx@kpmfAywSe0HkGtz@gIdUq38WyHpTvx85ErdAoP26bGhvdWusY3BNfGW5X9CYbx4NPKvwA)

`-` is there only to convert the chars to numbers (it doesn't matter if they are negative)

`{` `}\` applies a function until convergence, preserving intermediate results

`x+1` add 1 to each number in `x`

`^` "without" - the list on the left without elements that occur in the list on the right

`x^x^x+1` means `x` intersected with `x+1`

`1_` drop the first element

`#` count

Comment: `#1_{x^x^x+1}\-`?

Comment: @Adám yeah, one day I should make trains work...

Comment: conceptualizing this as the intersection with the increment until convergence is quite nice

Comment: trains work­­­­

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>12</s> 10 bytes

```
91:wX-dX>q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8N/S0Ko8Qjclwq7wv0vIf/VwxxBnD3UudUe/EE8Xz2DX4BBHJx/PYA9fV78QxyBPRz/PYF@gNFA4KBhIOzk6e7v4@weBdABxSGiIP1CRT7A6AA)

#### Explanation:

`91:` - Create the list of numbers from 1 to 91. 91 is character '[', which comes after 'Z'.
So this effectively creates the list of all characters from '\x1' to '['. (We mainly want
those in the range ['A'-1 : 'Z'+1], but having the rest doesn't hurt, and needs less bytecount.)

`w`   - Implicit input, bring input to top of stack (assume 'TUTORIALS')

`X-`  - Set difference. This leaves only the characters that were *not* found in the 
input string, in their original order ('stable'). Stack: `'    !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@BCDEFGHJKMNPQVWXYZ['`

`d`   - Difference between successive elements in that list. Stack: `[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 5 1 1 1 1 1]`

`X>`  - Get the maximum of those differences i.e. the max number of consecutive alphabets missing from the set difference.

`q`   - Decrement to get actual character count

---

Older:

#### 12 bytes

```
Sud1=Y'*X>sQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8D@4NMXQNlJdK8KuOPC/S8h/9fLEkuQMdS71xLySzJTM4tTiksSknMzijNzUvJLEoszEvMziXKA0ULioGEgnJSZnp@TnF4F0AHFJaUk@UFFOsToA)

Comment: So many approaches :-)

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 100 bytes

```c
c,o,u;n(t,e,r)char*r,*e,*t;{for(u=0,e=t;c=*t++;u=u<o?o:u)for(o=0,r=e;*r;*r++-c||(c++,r=e,++o));o=u;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU5LasMwEF03pzAqxvqMoaVdRRW@RFbGG0WWY9FYKtKILpKc3ZWTQmAY5n0Z056MWVcDAbL0FMFCZGbWkUfgFjjKyxQizeoNrEJpFEchZFb5K3Rhn9kmhiJGZSWPZYRozfVKjRAbB0IExmRQWd7W19FOztvqQHuw7Cc6jxMlng6kTgNhlarqserum9aGDZ5AD572rDxl2@3omqnZN9gwuVu085Rddi8HSn41mplA9c7uMKGOqcCPB9Qe3eiSLfTx7NK8WF8MTnuXlqfrqM33GEIszOd/7tmIGUNJnNNDva1/)

## Explanation

```c
c,o,u;n(t,e,r)    // setup, function declaration
char*r,*e,*t;{    // K&R style
 for(u=0,e=t;     // initialize global maximum u to 0, write string start to e
 c=*t++;          // look at every character in the string
 u=u  <o?o:  u)   // funny face
  for(o=0,r=e;*r; // initialize local maximum o to 0, look at entire string again
  *r++-c||(c++,   // equal character found, search for next one
   r=e,++o));     // reset local pointer, increment local maximum
o=u;}             // return maximum character streak
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZLBcpswEEDP5St26LhGIE/SSU6hjD@gt05OHl9ksRiNQeuKVRM3ybe7i03spDqApGWf3q6wi621x6PVpGPpM9aogwIZNzcwIMe9hiZ6y4481Gg7E8w4T2xrQh50jjrn8mVK@PntFwx86DCBhkIWq1uNFZcwhZ137Ezn/iJsO9qYDnrz7PrYQwQmuNXwFByjIILzW3mZwGNAcLbKuSjOpHdcR7QDw4B/MBxgFDKWMcgxwO07JYFYRYAftKQHgKjOqVKSP0BjrKBPqiSqocIyD@V/ph3ZD6I0iV7O9uzCxdhsjfNCzENRLOzra2aLQp9PxN9RMFfJhqKvtbTYBNuOCuDxmYH8aASioouClLr0LqDcxiSzJ@eFoUXTBuzF4bNlQlUs3@DjOBE4Bn@p5Koi8mh2x681Ns4jPGYrjWovBXGTpT5bp7NhnSqoYFbD8vTMZlatfapX2mcrJb8MLsbJct7MH@Y8V2XSSyMy9ZJ8eczSJ8O2TTV8V6fleK2DLO/OSyMdrN2Asr3p3NCO5ZjgjHdDf/1qY@yuJgqycz/lXYkcmSSjG87Rt@M/)

Comment: +1 for the "c,o,u;n(t,e,r)" :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 54 bytes

```
O`.
D`.
.
$&$&¶
T`l`_l`¶.
(.)¶\1
$1
.(.+)
$.1
O#^`
1G`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYtBCsMgFAX37xq1wVD44B0KXWbTZUn9SYR8ahSipTfzAF7MupjFDMzpsgRuV/2wbbKEe4egBjXUgqf19u1tLQRNYy0vA2VAmm4jFBlMl9nC9LP9OK87UuYzgUOWTZLrtnhJ@@FC78JB0oGF188W4wlG/ubYs09/) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
O`.
```

Sort the letters into order.

```
D`.
```

Deduplicate the letters.

```
.
$&$&¶
```

Duplicate each letter on separate lines.

```
T`l`_l`¶.
```

Decrement the first of each pair.

```
(.)¶\1
$1
```

If this now matches the previous character, join them back together.

```
.(.+)
$.1
```

Count the lengths of all the runs.

```
O#^`
```

Sort them in reverse numerical order.

```
1G`
```

Take the first (largest).

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <strike>98</strike> 92 bytes

Thanks to Jonathan Frech for the suggestions.

Uppercase-only.

```c
f(char*s){int a[99]={0},i,j,k=j=i=0;for(;*s;a[*s++]++);for(;i<99;j=!!a[i++]*++j,k=j>k?j:k);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY27DoIwGIV3n6JiTHrT6Ii1GIwmNlEGYSMMTRH9QdGAuhCevQJuJ9@5mdnVGDuB0tw/6QWt63cKz/nNsxk2N13RmjRQvpGOXTeRzaLlwHNeyFyCXIjsWWFBa6FjWjOWMEb@CNauK3I5HusYOk4ZGzpesclXBRGt7ScfGko8bFdXw/szRGmnvwQ1I4Qgw73hLQl6VV0sw840dTga8DdeJoSIUWutH0Rqp8J9GPnbowoPp30Q@WflByo8/QA)

Comment: You do not actually need the `k;` at the end. Implicit gcc returning is a side effect of variable assignment which appearently is executed as a last step in your for loop.

Comment: Possible [95 bytes](https://tio.run/##HY1BDoIwFET3nqLRmLSlGlxCLR6EsPgWkN9KNW11Q/DqFdhN5k3e6NND63RAp5@ftiPXEFt8nYcq9VQP4HlgE7pIoC6KolFTPgsURljZvzyVPEioeciyJsvYVqEyyqpc4nXZS6OgxoXeTj9T5sIqU9mbKS2Tc1qtI6Cjm94/tFj/COdL/jIy7QjBnq6gujDy9susp/tjuxdkq7/1pWFM7uaUwEVsMXQhwv2JYRg7F8EjOAzjHw).

Comment: @JonathanFrech I don't trust gcc's implicit returns. They don't always happen the way that I expect them to, and they often don't work at all for pointers and floating-point. Fortunately, outside of code golf I never use them! :-)

Answer (score 2):

## J, 16 bytes

*-7 bytes thanks to FrownyFrog*

```
[:>./a.#;._1@e.]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/o63s9PQT9ZSt9eINHVL1Yv9rcqUmZ@QrGCrYKqQpqJcnliRnqEOEjCFCxSWJRcWoQol5JZkpmcWpQKmknMzijNzUPKCizMS8zOJcqEoTiMqkxOTslPz8InUuEPgPAA)

### explanation

```
[: >./ a. #;._1@e. ]    
       a. (    )e. ]    is the ascii alphabet an element of the input:
                        this will transform the alphabet into a 1-0 array,
                        the ones representing the letters in the input
          #;._1@        split that 1-0 list up into pieces, using 0
                        as the delimiter, and transforming each chunk
                        into its length. now we have a list of ints
[: >./                  take the max
```

Comment: I think that you can use `]` instead of `~.@/:~` The alphabet is already sorted, so you don't need to sort the input and keep only the unique items.
[TIO - 18 bytes](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/o63s9PSjrZSt9eINFRL1UvVi/2typSZn5CsYKtgqpCmolyeWJGeoQ4SMIULFJYlFxahCiXklmSmZxalAqaSczOKM3NQ8oKLMxLzM4lyoShOIyqTE5OyU/PwidS4Q@A8A)

Comment: [16](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/o63s9PQT9ZSt9eINHVL1Yv9rcqUmZ@QrGCrYKqQpqJcnliRnqEOEjCFCxSWJRcWoQol5JZkpmcWpQKmknMzijNzUPKCizMS8zOJcqEoTiMqkxOTslPz8InUuEPgPAA)

Comment: @FrownyFrog and Galen, Thank you both!  In retrospect it should have been obvious I didn't need that uniq/sort first.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) `-h`, 9 bytes

Case insenstive, takes input as a string or an array of characters.

```
;CôkU mÊn
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=O0P0a1Ugbcpu&input=InR1dG9yaWFscyIKLWg=) or [run multiple tests](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=O0P0a1UgbcpuCmcxbg==&input=Wwoid2F0Y2giCiJzdGFycyIKImFudGlkaXNlc3RhYmxpc2htZW50YXJpYW5pc20iCiJiYWNrZG9vciIKImEiCiJ0dXRvcmlhbHMiCiJhYmNkZWZnaGlqa2xtbm9wcXJzdHV2d3h5eiIKIiIKIlVQUEVSQ0FTRSIKIjgiCl0KLW1S) (the second line serves as a replacement for the `-h` flag so the flag can be used to process multiple inputs instead)

---

### Explanation

```
              :Implicit input of string/array U
;C            :The lowercase alphabet
  ô           :Partition at characters returning truthy
   kU         :  Remove all characters in U from the current letter
              :  This will return a non-empty string (truthy) if the current letter ISN'T in U
     m        :Map
      Ê       :  Length
       n      :Sort
              :Implicitly output the last element in the array
```

Comment: @Downvoter, could you provide a reason for your `-1`, please?

Answer (score 2):

### Perl 5, 68 bytes

```
$"=<>;map{$"=~/$_/i&&++$$_||last for$_..z;$.=$$_ if$$_>$.}a..z;say$.
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19FydbGzjo3saAayKrTV4nXz1RT09ZWUYmvqclJLC5RSMsvUonX06uyVtGzBYoqZKYBSTsVvdpEkGBxYqWK3v//iU7JKalp6RmZWdk5uXn@BYVFxSWlZeUVlVX/8gtKMvPziv/r@prqGRgaAAA).

Ungolfed:

```perl
use feature 'say';

my $s = <>;
my $r;
for ('a' .. 'z') {
    my $c = 0;
    for ($_ .. 'z') {
        last if $s !~ /$_/i;
        $c++;
    }
    $r = $c if $c > $r;
}
say($r);
```

Answer (score 2):

### Perl 5, 62 + 2 (`-nF` flag) = 64 bytes

```
$c[ord lc$_]=1for@F;$y[y///c]++for"@c "=~/((1 )+)/g}{say@y/2|0
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##DchLCsMgEADQq0hwkSDpaCGrEnCVXU8QQrHGtgNGg7qRfo7ead/y7S75gYjbOaaVecsvy6huMenpxOtcAcAuQvyj0ZY14wfaVrFOdHB/P7OpusLxJYlMKLhidrmYq8f82FwoJqEJmLdv3AvGkKk/DwepJPVh@gE).

### Perl 5, 68 bytes

```
<>=~s/./$c[ord lc$&]=1/gre;$y[y///c]++for"@c "=~/((1 )+)/g;say@y/2|0
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##BcHRCoMgFADQ932FhIxC1rVBT@XoB/YF0YMz1y6YhtcXYfTpc@ccNrq@lPGhToIWuJlDXJkz/LqoDrZoB57nDABmEeIdYjUZVqkT6rpjjWhgG0jnKcP9K0vRPuGKZCnpl0P67NYnHVF7pP3yC0fC4Kncnn0rO/kH).

Comment: Nice approach! I'd not considered that method at all... You can save a few bytes using `-pF` and `-MList::Util+(max)` to get to 56: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dc27DsIgGEDhVyENA6RWikmXGpJOnXR0sg5IUf@EW4BBY/TRRbaTbzlBRzOUgtXZxxUZdRH85uM07/EirHziZfNijCm2q9pMCjXiywjhiLaU3T/vUqTLsELSKcurgfSw2mUZQTpI9udDBu9S6Y7Dtud96cJc@wApj@Mpg2lJfdA/ "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Comment: @DomHastings `-MList::Util=max` adds 16 bytes to the result score.

Comment: If I understand the new scoring correctly, command-line flags aren't counted as bytes, but as as a separately scored language, so rather than just Perl, it'd be Perl with `-MList::Util+(max)` `-pF`, or similar. https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/9365

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>66</s> <s>65</s> 63 bytes

Assumes input only contains lowercase letters. First, it loops over the string and sets bits in an integer according to which letters are seen. Next, it counts the longest streak of 1 bits in the integer.

Edit: `a` is global, so will be initialised to 0 at first call. The second loop makes sure it is reset to 0 before returning. Therefore, we can avoid resetting it manually.

```
a,l;f(char*s){for(l=0;*s;)a|=1<<*s++-97;for(;a;l++)a&=a*2;s=l;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY3NbsIwEITP9VNYkUB2fqTSS1WZ8CRcNnacuDg29RpogTx7aiIlt535Zmdk1Uk5TVBaoZnsIeTIH9oHZut3kaPg8Kx3@32ORVF9fYoXESBsUXDY1pB/CKytGKerN4p2cwFNDeRB3s7BuKhZtkFaHehGHV1WUiypZsi5ICMhidMBjGNzvmPZDaLsswRfAiMEXAS4aJTBNpmNNdgPrUvYgDM4LJkG5El5H9af5bivTiNVq7vefJ/s4Pz5J2C8XG@/f2siXqJPtXYeHqd/)

Answer (score 2):

## [SQLite](https://sqlite.org/lang.html) 265

```
WITH w AS(SELECT'a'w),n AS(SELECT 1 n UNION ALL SELECT n+1 FROM n LIMIT(SELECT length(w)FROM w)),l AS(SELECT substr(w,n,1)l FROM n,w)SELECT max(v)FROM(SELECT min(n)v FROM(SELECT*FROM l,n EXCEPT SELECT l.l,unicode(l.l)-unicode(b.l)d FROM l,l b WHERE d>0)GROUP BY l);
```

Ungolfed:

```
WITH w AS (SELECT 'antidisestablishmentarianism' w)
   , n AS (SELECT 1 n
           UNION ALL
           SELECT n+1 FROM n
           LIMIT (SELECT length(w) FROM w) )
   , l AS (SELECT DISTINCT substr(w,n,1) l FROM n,w ORDER BY l)
   , d AS (
           SELECT l,n FROM l,n
           EXCEPT
           SELECT a.l l, unicode(a.l) - unicode(b.l) d 
           FROM l a, l b 
           WHERE d > 0 
           )

SELECT max(v) FROM ( SELECT min(d.n) v FROM d GROUP BY d.l );
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>14</s> <s>13</s> 12 bytes

```
{⊇pS∧ẠsSl}ᶠ⌉
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATEAzv9icmFjaHlsb2cy//974oqHcFPiiKfhuqBzU2x94bag4oyJ//8idHV0b3JpYWxzIv9a)

```
{        }ᶠ    % Find all values that satisfy this predicate
           ⌉   % And get their maximum
               % The predicate being:
 ⊇pS           % There exists a permutation of a subset of the input
               %  Call it S
    ∧          % And, 
      sS       % S is a substring of
     Ạ         %  the set of alphabets, Ạ, 
        l      % Then, the length of that substring is the return value of the 
               %  predicate
```

Slow enough that it doesn't finish for input "antidisestablishmentarianism" on TIO. Relatively much faster one for +1 byte:

#### 13 bytes

```
{dosS∧ẠsSl}ᶠ⌉
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/vzolvzj4Ucfyh7sWFAfn1D7ctuBRT@f//0pJicnZKfn5RUr/owA)

Use `dos` instead of `⊇p`: S is a `d`eduplicated s`o`rted `s`ubstring of the input, instead of just some permutation of some subset.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>63</s> 59 bytes

Not very golfy.

-4 bytes thanks to [manatwork](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4198/manatwork)

```ruby
->s{s.bytes.uniq.sort.slice_when{_2!=_1+1}.map(&:size).max}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsEiN9ulpSVpuhY3rXXtiquL9ZIqS1KL9UrzMgv1ivOLSvSKczKTU-PLM1LzquONFG3jDbUNa_VyEws01KyKM6tSNYHsilqoEcoFCm7RSol5JZkpmcWpxSWJSTmZxRm5qXkliUWZiXmZxblKsRClCxZAaAA)

Comment: If you use `.bytes` instead of `.chars` then you can save on replacing `.succ` with `+1`.

Comment: @manatwork Ah, of course. Thanks!

Comment: `.slice_when` is 1 character shorter than `.chunk_while`, just have to reverse the `==` into `!=`.

Comment: @manatwork Nice. Thanks!

Comment: I promise to not bother you more with this. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XVDLSsNAFMVl8hUXbBilSdpQF1KYZmVBXBTishSZTEYSmhe5E6ym8UfcBNGP0q9x8mgDbu7jnHsO996Pr6L0X5vPNf0u5bN1-zO1Vlhducy23bdrO2F5NbEp0vfZZfXk1DN3Yk-d5bxWzKHuJb8XD3kpEYhhLeYIhnMOSMCALblPFU9MIJ7AMu6qu0MuuBRBWz-WnAtEstMrXSMvTPKQAF2BY6oWJSuwaxdty1IZBREKBftxhGEiUjUQsTTCZJzyGd8HWVZ0yE2nGx1lKTOliPHE1rZgPIQgg2PUbmqCGLY76lrRrQwU1tuO3Onav2ODIfTHDg69bHQ6IUDpGQMXyGZPYKne4XkbTz1ApEH_06bp8x8)

Comment: @manatwork You ought to post that as your own answer. It’s an entirely different technique. Very nice, too.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 7 bytes

```
CÞǔ0€∩L
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJDw57HlDDigqziiKlMIiwiIiwiYW50aWRpc2VzdGFibGlzaG1lbnRhcmlhbmlzbSJd)

Port of Jelly.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 43 characters

```ruby
->s{(?a..?z).map{$.=s=~/#{_1}/?$.+1:0}.max}
```

Sample run:

```
bash-5.1$ ruby -e 'p ->s{(?a..?z).map{$.=s=~/#{_1}/?$.+1:0}.max}["backdoor"]'
4
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XVDLSsNAFMVl8hUXbBilSdpQF1KYZmVBXBTishSZTEYSmhe5E6ym8UfcBNGP0q9x8mgDbu7jnHsO996Pr6L0X5vPNf0u5bN1-zO1Vlhducy23bdrO2F5NbEp0vfZZfXk1DN3Yk-d5bxWzKHuJb8XD3kpEYhhLeYIhnMOSMCALblPFU9MIJ7AMu6qu0MuuBRBWz-WnAtEstMrXSMvTPKQAF2BY6oWJSuwaxdty1IZBREKBftxhGEiUjUQsTTCZJzyGd8HWVZ0yE2nGx1lKTOliPHE1rZgPIQgg2PUbmqCGLY76lrRrQwU1tuO3Onav2ODIfTHDg69bHQ6IUDpGQMXyGZPYKne4XkbTz1ApEH_06bp8x8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 87 bytes

```hs
import Data.List
maximum.map length.filter(`isInfixOf`['a'..'z']).subsequences.nub.sort
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcxBCsJADADAu68IRVi95Ae9eREEHyBCU8na4CbWTRaKn1@dB8xC/uJSehdd3zXgREF4EY9dHpU20aaotEJhe8aCWUpwPUziZ8uyXfN0S5QQ0zfdj@htdv40tgc7WpvR/2VXEoMR1ioWsIcMgwdVH/oP)

Expects lowercase characters

Explanation:

```hs
maximum.map length.filter(`isInfixOf`['a'..'z']).subsequences.nub.sort
                                                                  sort {- sort the characters -}
                                                              nub      {- remove duplicates -}
                                                 subsequences          {- all subsequences -}
                   filter(`isInfixOf`['a'..'z'])                       {- all characters are adjacent -}
        map length                                                     {- length of filtered subsequences -}
maximum                                                                {- maxmimum length -}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 95 bytes

```python
lambda s:max(reduce(lambda(p,v),c:(c,v+[v[-1]*(c==p+1)+1]),map(ord,sorted(set(s))),(0,[0]))[1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY1LbsQgEETXySnY0cQ90jhLS56LEC8wYBnFfET3OMnpCU42pVK9J1X54T2n97bNH@0wcXVG0BTNN1TvntbD/wYFT4V2AovnoE99G5c3sPNchlEN46IwmgK5OqRc2Tsgz0BKKYQ76vuilO5S23IVJEISWn4ZtrtEIYlNpauYxMEF8n1Yj0B79KmjYFKgePHV2E@Xc/1zr@An584Pksv0@lJqSCwI5e0hcevnrf0C)

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth - 11 bytes

```
le@.:G).:S{
```

Input must be wrapped in quotes. If not allowed:

## Pyth - 12 bytes

```
le@.:G).:S{z
```

Explanation:

```
l(
  e(
    @(
      .:(G),
      .:(
         S(
           {(Q)
         )
      )
    )
  )
)
length(
    last element(
        intersection(
            all positive length substrings(the alphabet as string),
            all positive length substrings(
                sorted(
                    uniquified(input)
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 97 bytes

```
{w:String->{var s=0
var m=0
for(c in 'a'..'z')if(c in w)s++
else{if(s>m)m=s
s=0}
if(s>m)m=s
m}()}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVZdb9s2FH3Xr7gxitluHbldi3Uz5gBZ0A4BguVhedneaImyiEikRlJRHMO/PTuXpJxkKNI9WeT9OvfcD/rW@Ebpx@VburBSeFlSZSz5WjkqTClpa5qKilo0jdRbucpq7zu3Wi5ZyLLceVHcynuoQJ4Xpl3@00vnldFu@eGnnz/9@Dm7ML32dIEbWfRe3Um6qIUVhZfWZdnvuNAkyHmr9BZRtRdK86fRzY4a6VlvQab3Xe8BTRJj8TWZKp4MIjtPttd8VTyLI5quFhvpVSGa0VOwGYwtx1DwPdTSSsKdtFQa6UgbT61g/ZzONcl70XYN@9saq3zdQrgjZ6w/eluQla1BzLLvGsTzEn6FLllB/y/weXbDXxfCSdAyCF/UdHpGHzJQDNj4/JgJ7VWpoODFplGubiVSsEpo5dqosUE5SoMa4vQpE9GD7z1wi8bF2@wr5CknBvmKz5GjBD0yKDalrFXTatQsp5uXaUAMLiEM2VvnF7QxMeGU@sc8@8N4TvIv0wcmvbhlclEjM0hbgIFFOPZdNx6BuFX3sjzl4xMSR0qDWcRI9AZxITRXUOrQw0qjp1FN9CSgm/6paDRTucxpBxjJpGUkLK4UoJPm3k@tCpVOedGoB0xJ7BhNyr1e1HmeZTc8TWmgTnloFmgdcjXah7WEdkgaKGmzwwUNoDvP3i6zbLmkL/cdaETAOyDgBFKI40gGr3lWofk7awrp3IwzW9GfYZ7mtKZ9lhHB19/SmmDs@jaWI5KoePysGeiHIG3FvWr7Ntrovt0AXIURLhl1JWxsa14TUqBFO@Oc2jQy6kefC@CTxS15pClRgIqUZwYQKcQP0HK6rKKRMwuICgwQWi9opLAjspyucWsHdOkimsDlwNsJ9JGWwwgazArMoPIRpGgGsXPRwkonv@0c8jthAytrep9OcJhOnOns2AZsNhXTPJ8@TOeQEkN5KWb@o4jY6bt34Vs2aMx9umYbjnfGcUZdSkFdID9ZJxBEh5h2qmUYOoHuYZVWbWt8eYWR0RLNAt43MtYAJ5EYEHqHxY7FKnXJP5zJw5Rq4fTU8yjtpOeiJGaT0XfpBbO@t6Gy0SQpM6/fyPN5jvjODrN5Flo9bL/SYm/bwPmxxWN3t1hDM2G3bkXn1ordr7HBz@bH/r4S7aYUBOUizPp/nMS6drTmYL98jtP2uB9W0dHp2T50wfp9FuqPXziYFS8Krqp4Mcwdysol3ePKnbXzdu0y2B6yZ@cWuR0eA7ZzjEXbea7MNrVhevAqa9pw7h0SB60LrnIwClO3GOcatD@fA9jwzAp@nQrZccaco7e71GV3ePPCglmjQqK8UlrO5icnuTdXvGX5nZk9dTBr5mmNrdFzY1PGKJcgcSuac7vteUa/jBFnk0tev@hALAG9PZlEsw6Z@QbSNwEAHp03@y6EmB@gErO7foYcC8PgNRIqvhpjxkxLKSvRN6kbgzte8Y5zPeATr@RMWmvsCjMBqHjD5DwxcITxmyjHd6JnnKNTNwIeuXIgS3B3XVezSXiCJwuahAd4sjiO6eS1J5MNxkf4hQ0Ljg9xiht2S0iKVyMDGHn/DoVxH6DY2SGOHP7E/Qs)

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 77 bytes

```java
int i,j,m;
c->{for(i=j=0;(m=j<c.length?m|1<<c[j++]:m&m*2+0*++i)>0;);return i;}
```

Port of [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld)'s C [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/168446/79343). Try it online [here](https://tio.run/##ZVLBbtswDD07X0H4MNi16ybtsA110qLINmBYhwHbMchBkZVYri25Ep0uy/LtGSWnWdoBhijz8ZFPJCu2Zue6FaoqHvZtt6glB14za@Ebkwq2g0AqBJlWaZPDxQUkMBrCYoPCekSYJeMCplpZwTuUa@EonsN1pzDiJTOzOTjDOIXbOB8Eu0FwKGWRIZm1lgU0VDD6iUaqFTGYWdnYJ1PiyYuJXlJ7l484Lc9P7hPY8/Ob7VKbSE6qyTCPmkk15lkt1ArL2@bPaDzmsypJ5tfNm@bsMhmeJYmMb4Z5nBuBnVEg890@CKhwcFRGb8cps8JSfqftCGzDJ4a8DFMI6V3GugtTKAtJwchItS0boQiSTEnbOHzB@EOhtfGx7sAONeG1Z/8WC@O9K10XS6l4Kby/ZUY/dgL7H6NbqR47ibJHl0IULm@4y/tZkDbxqxXU/@KHsF2Nz9J7bDtK4cp/b1MY@fMyhff@@5DCO5/GN9GtAlGHOZkxTQDLrKEpHDty6Gz6utzBH@fg@utn5nfEeJgynkwt6xfnmHMm5xnqKS3QnTFsE8VuDWgcG4uiyXSHWUv9x1q9oNCihtcQkjnUSCCKnstNXusjQgy3FB59/xqH4IjR57sv958@/ntKn@1/oqsUh72qnVvQ3f4v).

Ungolfed:

```java
int i, j, m; // instance variables of the surrounding class - initialised to 0
c -> { // lambda - c is of type char[]; return type is int
    for(i = j = 0; // i is the length of the longest run, j is used to step through c - both start at 0
        (m = j < c.length // work with the bitmask of all the letters present in c: if we have not reached the end of c ...
             ? m | 1 << c[j++] // ... set the bit corresponding to the current character, advance one character ...
             : m & m * 2 + 0 * ++i) > 0 ;) ; // ... else reduce runs of consecutively set bits in m by AND-combining it with a left-shifted copy of itself until m hits 0
    return i; // return the result - by now m is back to 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 63 bytes

Reads lowercase characters from stdin, outputs a number to stdout.

```
0l55*)?\
8/?(0:i<]r1~r[-*c
~/00
}</?)@:{:*+1/?(3l
  \~:03. ;n~/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/3yDH1FRL0z6Gy0LfXsPAKtMmtsiwrihaVyuZq07fwICr1kbfXtPBqtpKS9sQqMI4h0tBIabOysBYT8E6r07///@S0pL8oszEnGIA)

```
0l55*)?\             Push 26 zeroes onto the stack

Record which characters are used
      i              Read a character from the input
 /?(0:               Check if it is -1, marking the end of the input
8             -*c    Subtract 96 from the character code, 
                         giving 1 for 'a', 2 for 'b' etc.
            r[       Pop that many values on to a new stack and reverse 
                         it, putting that character's value at the top of 
                         the stack
          1~         Write 1 to that value
        ]r           Return the stack back to it's normal state

Count the longest run of ones in the stack
  00                 Push values for currentRun = 0, and bestRun = 0
}                    Move bestRun to the bottom of the stack
            /?(3l    Check if there are only 2 values left on the stack
          +1         Increment currentRun
         *           Multiply currentRun by the next value in the stack, 
                         resetting it to 0 if the run is broken
  /?)@:{:            Check if currentRun > bestRun
  \~:                Overwrite bestRun if so
     03.             Jump back to the start of loop
         ;n~/        Once all values have been consumed, 
                         print bestRun and exit
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 7 bytes

```
L►Lġ≈Ou
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/3@fRtF0@RxY@6uzwL/3//39SYnJ2Sn5@EQA)

First time I've used `simil(≈)`, and it works really well!

### Explanation

```
L►Lġ≈Ou 
     Ou order and deduplicate
   ġ≈   group by absolute difference ≤ 1
 ►L     max by length
L       take the length of that
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 63 bytes

```
Length[Alphabet[]~LongestCommonSubsequence~Union@Characters@#]&
```

[View it on Wolfram Cloud!](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/7c977374-5c6f-4480-99f5-693cf528abee)

Mathematica's verbosity is a blessing and a curse, as usual. [`LongestCommonSubsequence`](https://reference.wolframcloud.com/language/ref/LongestCommonSubsequence.html) is exactly the right tool for the job, but its an astounding 24 bytes! (Also, as usual, strings being atoms is frustrating.)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `G`, 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
Ạ€Ƈġʂ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVFMSVCQSVBMCVFMiU4MiVBQyVDNiU4NyVDNCVBMSVDQSU4MiZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PSUyMndhdGNoJTIyJTIwLSUzRSUyMDElMEElMjJzdGFycyUyMiUyMC0lM0UlMjAzJTBBJTIyYW50aWRpc2VzdGFibGlzaG1lbnRhcmlhbmlzbSUyMiUyMC0lM0UlMjAzJTBBJTIyYmFja2Rvb3IlMjIlMjAtJTNFJTIwNCUwQSUyMmElMjIlMjAtJTNFJTIwMSUwQSUyMnR1dG9yaWFscyUyMiUyMC0lM0UlMjA0JmZsYWdzPUNH)

Port of Adnan's 05AB1E answer.

##### Explanation

```python
Ạ€Ƈġʂ  # Implicit input
Ạ      # Push the lowercase alphabet
 €     # For each letter in this string:
  Ƈ    #  Is it in the input string?
   ġ   # Group consecutive items together
    ʂ  # Sum each inner group
       # Implicit output of maximum sum
```