# Socket - Plug compatibility

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, combinatorics, alphabet

Traveling with electronics is always fun, especially when you need an adapter to charge them. Your challenge is to make planning a trip a little easier by checking if a given plug will be compatible with a given socket.

#### Challenge

Given a plug type and a socket type, return a value that indicates whether they will work together or not.

#### Compatibility table

```
Socket  Accepted plugs  |  Plug  Accepting Sockets
A       A               |  A     A, B
B       A, B            |  B     B
C       C               |  C     C, D, E, F, H, J, K, L, N, O
D       C, D, E, F      |  D     D
E       C, E, F         |  E     D, E, F, H, K, O
F       C, E, F         |  F     D, E, F, H, K, O
G       G               |  G     G
H       C, E, F, H      |  H     H
I       I               |  I     I
J       C, J            |  J     J
K       C, E, F, K      |  K     K
L       C, L            |  L     L
M       M               |  M     M
N       C, N            |  N     N
O       C, E, F, O      |  O     O
```

<sup>The tables show the same information, only transposed.</sup>

[For reference](https://www.worldstandards.eu/electricity/plugs-and-sockets/).

#### Input

- The input will be given as two uppercase or two lowercase letters (you choose).
- Inputs will always be `/[A-O]/` (or `/[a-o]/`), there's no need to handle invalid inputs.
- You may accept the two inputs in any order (please specify which).
- Input can be taken in [any reasonable format](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) (string, stdin, array, ...).
- If you take both inputs in a single string, they can be separated by no more  than one character and there must be nothing surrounding them
- Good inputs: `"G,K"`, `"EF"`, `"a b"`, `['l', 'o']`
- Bad inputs: `"K l"`, `"f(O)(I)"`, `[1,5]`

#### Output

- Output can be returned in [any reasonable format](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods).
- Output must be either `truthy`/`falsy` or one of 2 constant values
- Good outputs: `false`/`any positive number`, `1`/`2`, `'T'`/`'F'`
- Bad outputs: `an even number`/`an odd number`, `1`/`more than 1`

#### Examples

Using the format `socket`, `plug` => `true` / `false`.

```
A, A => true
I, K => false
O, C => true
C, O => false
E, F => true
F, E => true
```

[Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are disallowed.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the answer with the fewest bytes in each language wins.

Comment: My country uses only C and F, I have also seen J... but why are there so many???

Comment: @AlexRacer Here, have some [reading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_power_plugs_and_sockets), there's also the weird shaver plug and the Italian extra wide plug and some others. Europlug is masterplug tho.

Answer (score 7):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), <s>30</s> 29 bytes

```
(.)\1|[DEFHKO][CEF]|[JLN]C|BA
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wX0NPM8awJtrF1c3D2z822tnVLbYm2svHL9a5xsnx/39HRy5Pby5/Zy5nfy5XNy43VwA) Link includes test cases.

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 76 bytes

```python
lambda s,p:any([s==p,p in"CEF"and s in"DEFHKO",s=="B"<p,s in"JLN"and"C"==p])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZAxb4MwEIX3/IrTTURyhyobioeUYqVNFRY2iiqXQINCjWUbVfn19Gygoh6s7@7ee/JZ3921V7ux4e9jJ78/LxIs07FU96iwnGumoVWYpAKluoD1xXMqjqcMGY3xCfeahe7r29lLMEFyldvR1HbonAUOBR4OOTJ8OQm6s8RzknlOhWeR5lhumt7A5KG0mWy8ATq2r261Y6C74YuBVPanNpQ7aYKiGVT1Mbs5NNHasQ2KP9cCHDDHMKp6Y@rK/ZutAoNGm1a5aGoU8cNjubyDraWMdm3VnEebLVQWM9G//AI)

## Credits:

- From 83 to 76 bytes by [(Better) Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil)

Comment: `lambda s,p:any([s==p,p in"CEF"and s in"DEFHKO",s=="B"<p,s in"JLN"and"C"==p])` for 76 bytes?

Comment: @Neil Thanks I updated that.

Comment: So funny haha Better Niel

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>72 Bytes</s> <s>73 bytes</s> 70 bytes

```python
lambda p,s:s in{"A":"AB","C":y+"CJLN","E":y,"F":y}.get(p,p)
y="DEFHKO"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZDBb4IwFMbP61/R9CRZ42G7kXBQFBEQl@y4LQRZ1WZAK5Qsxvm3s9enmbIemt/Xvve9r9VHs1f1c3/w3vsyrzafOdW8dVsq6xObMJdNpowzn7nHR@ZHSQpiDoKzAPbzeCfMSHPtkKPHZvMgjNesl5VWjaHSiMYoVbaE6LLbZUZlrSq@hKEePZGHP3PAKeCFYBDzrVEUJ@kaj2ZwNEOaW7oMsTIYygXIBVIIFCItgZZIEVCEFAPFSAlQgrQCWiGlQCnSGsg6nwkxorWpIa7NtgiXkG4F8Uihqk3r3Z46tgeyzo1UdZt9S7PPGqHLvBCVqM3I@nD65BCyVQ21v8Lp9U9kTdHMJRRWXpguL6G37Uo7@VY0/Mo3Kz@wZdvVxa3hMLp3d7ACN91ICMJe4NalpzP9oa9YchETnHu9CMDxir5qGlFgERtD9io3gwF8mJjfp@H/X@Pd3zpO/ws)

Edit: Thanks to [Chas Brown](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/69880/chas-brown) for cutting some fat!

Comment: Found a typo that caused C, C to return false.

Comment: Nice! `q=` can be omitted since the function is anonymous. Also, there's an extra space. [70 bytes. Try it online.](https://tio.run/##XZDBb4IwFMbP61/R9CRZ42G7kXBQFBEQl@y4LQRZ1WZAK5Qsxvm3s9enmbIemt/Xvve9r9VHs1f1c3/w3vsyrzafOdW8dVsq6xObMJdNpowzn7nHR@ZHSQpiDoKzAPbzeCfMSHPtkKPHZvMgjNesl5VWjaHSiMYoVbaE6LLbZUZlrSq@hKEePZGHP3PAKeCFYBDzrVEUJ@kaj2ZwNEOaW7oMsTIYygXIBVIIFCItgZZIEVCEFAPFSAlQgrQCWiGlQCnSGsg6nwkxorWpIa7NtgiXkG4F8Uihqk3r3Z46tgeyzo1UdZt9S7PPGqHLvBCVqM3I@nD65BCyVQ21v8Lp9U9kTdHMJRRWXpguL6G37Uo7@VY0/Mo3Kz@wZdvVxa3hMLp3d7ACN91ICMJe4NalpzP9oa9YchETnHu9CMDxir5qGlFgERtD9io3gwF8mJjfp@H/X@Pd3zpO/ws)

Comment: Thanks! For some reason I thought that the lambda would capture y, which is why I had written it that way initially.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG, and nice first post!

Comment: @user202729: Hadn't seen that before; nice tip to know.

Comment: @ChasBrown That really confuses me. >.< I thought that cokment was of OP so I deleted the comment.

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/) (x86 architecture), <strike>76</strike> 60 bytes

Many thanks to Arnauld for the changes!

Arguments are given in (plug, socket) order.

```c
c[15]={6,0,56696,0,35184,35184};f(a,b){a=a==b|c[a-65]>>b&1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZDfToMwFMbv9xQnNZMSihnREl0pi29gondjF6XA1oqwQPEGeXakoFtMvDn/vt93TnKkf5RyvFGVLLssh6g1marvTvEo9wE98D4kG0LD8Mnmexo8PixxYAUWJHV7wQXn6ZfcCz@khzhObwM2jKoy8CFUhT9rlbnQrwDkSTQwWdhUW1kRbctzMzUFRi9ld0zMmoZtUiGCXmv5nhvkWqSoG6y4HzAVBZQpz1sWAgiuPOfZYXNjKW0pbSl9pQBSrq/cdL0ArKKNe7m9lolBBLCehjsHnG3q/rJ52eazQf9jEH@xi9rO6vKgHXpruhxtkY9@6GGO5860GC2zYTWM3w)

Comment: Using the reference you provided [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/168427/count-consecutive-characters/168446#comment407153_168446) about x86 architectures: you can save 3 bytes by doing `1<<~-b`.

Comment: [66 bytes](https://tio.run/##bZDfToMwFMbv9xQnNZM2FDM2mXMFF9/AZN5tuygFtlaEBYo3iK@OLegWE2/Ov@/3nZMc4R2F6G9kIfImSSGsdSLLu9NTL3Z@cIjaBZ3R@WpxvzLZfwge52PsWIY5jUnLIyx23FsGh08/DL88Tm6HHLOul4WGdy4L/FHKhEA7ARAnXoExMlNbWVJly3Nlmgyjl7w57vU0WNb7AlG0LcVbqhGxSFZWWEaez2ToB0y67rgQgEfSdZ4dNjSWUpZSllJXCiCO1JUz1zPAMpyRy@2p2GtEASsz3DjgrGPyy6Z5nQ4G9Y@B/8Uuaj2o45s26LVqUrRGHvqhuyGeG11jNM66Sdd/Aw) by getting rid of _d_ and the ternary operator.

Comment: [62 bytes](https://tio.run/##bZDfToMwFMbv9xQnNZMSilmjJboCi29gondjF6XA1oqwQPEGeXakoFtMvDn/vt93TnKkf5RyvFGVLLssh7A1marvTvEo95Qdoj4gG8KC4Mnme0YfH5Y48AILkrq9iLDcCz9ghy8ahsKN4/SW8mFUlYEPoSr8WavMhX4FIE@igcnEp9rKimhbnpupKTB6KbtjYtYsaJMKEfRay/fcINciRd1gFfmUq5AyrjxvWQggIuU5zw6fG0tpS2lL6SsFkEb6yk3XC8Aq3LiX22uZGEQA62m4c8DZpu4vm5dtPhv0PwbxF7uo7awuL9qht6bL0Rb56Ice5njuTIvRMhtWw/gN) by doubling the bitmasks. Now beating all languages but Jelly and Retina! \o/

Comment: [60 bytes](https://tio.run/##bZDfToMwFMbv9xQnNZMSihnREl0pi29gondjF6XA1oqwQPEGeXakoFtMvDn/vt93TnKkf5RyvFGVLLssh6g1marvTvEo9wE98D4kG0LD8Mnmexo8PixxYAUWJHV7wQXn6ZfcCz@khzhObwM2jKoy8CFUhT9rlbnQrwDkSTQwWdhUW1kRbctzMzUFRi9ld0zMmoZtUiGCXmv5nhvkWqSoG6y4HzAVBZQpz1sWAgiuPOfZYXNjKW0pbSl9pQBSrq/cdL0ArKKNe7m9lolBBLCehjsHnG3q/rJ52eazQf9jEH@xi9rO6vKgHXpruhxtkY9@6GGO5860GC2zYTWM3w) by just comparing _a_ with _b_.

Comment: Suggest `L"\6\0\xdd78\0襰襰"` instead of `{6,0,56696,0,35184,35184}`

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, 67 bytes

```
p#s=p==s||or[elem s b|a:b<-words"AB CDEFHJKLNO EDFHKO FDEHKO",a==p]
```

Arguments to function `#` are two characters, plug first, socket second.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcfRCoIwFIDh@57ioBdzYD1AtAvTDctqDyAS04SkqWNLIvDd1yHYxc/P91Tu1WvtvYkdM4y5dZ1t3et@BAftqvbtYfuZ7cNF2RHygovyXF1uEnghykqCKDguShVjpvGjGiZgMCpzvUNi7DC9YQfL1C3WfpOYUqg3AAnJSIrR9I8KcQrIETJAIvIAgeABHCEIbfwP)

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 79 bytes

```javascript
S=>P=>P==S|P<'B'&S<'C'|P=='C'&'JLN'[K='includes'](S)|'CEF'[K](P)&'DEFHKO'[K](S)
```

Invoked as a curried function, `f(socket)(plug)`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZJtb6owFMff8ymOuZttEy57P8cWRZ3zOeElIRkXy4ZywbQ676J8dnfawpTkDiH@2p7zP09dRx@RjEW63f3OixU/n@/uwIuyDA7p7h0iIaJPCGQRb/jOhm22fwutuMjlDrpCgAs0sUHiAQP3ERIaKA6ZVYtEEuK9EClfATUijCoRVol4@/@ISLRhVmURKB0bkjwE1wIIlIsNvvu4VK/rn5YPpEfa/gPxyAk38K9NxtM5CSYuSfM426@4JCH12Yl4gyFuh3TJ2qQ/GI4mC730GYSdOp7KzteZzqIt5nbEoN17IN0esRF7iIY8JE@pjCfT@UJv9XGrr2mgyERQy2Fz@YzLZ00jpJGmF6QXTWOksaYJ0kTTFGmqaYY00zRHmmtaICnlsqqiyLiTFW@UAD63ktiw@LPm8c7Z8E9JGxUyZ12kubIkjHWspBBAM27aAGnebAfT3VDHojhgbwJsG8C3jxnwD14Apr/83xYzwfvgNq0CfbecemL1belcuQoe8/RDu/YKrDHKqbocNMltuL6hrOH1NxIb9LjEdS9CT0Dwh91rEeOCdTnbvXynrzdH5VjeHK@Nf2ljh5TV6WsVKU2AfgdoXQLUpZtc1FgOkcBu97r9FjHJ1qlXSqVlvsYYb@W9GaNxUEmaqemZldb5/AU) (includes testcases, showing a matrix of results.)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 31 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Oḅ⁴_ȷe“j⁼⁽⁾ƇƑƓƘƝƤḄẸỊṂṢỴẒĊḞĿ‘o⁼/
```

A monadic link accepting a list of characters `[plug,socket]` which yields `1` if compatible or `0` if not.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AVQAq/9qZWxsef//T@G4heKBtF/It2XigJxq4oG84oG94oG@xofGkcaTxpjGncak4biE4bq44buK4bmC4bmi4bu04bqSxIrhuJ7Ev@KAmG/igbwv////RUM)** Or see a [test-suite](https://tio.run/##AYEAfv9qZWxsef//T@G4heKBtF/It2XigJxq4oG84oG94oG@xofGkcaTxpjGncak4biE4bq44buK4bmC4bmi4bu04bqSxIrhuJ7Ev@KAmG/igbwv/@KAnEFCQ0RFRkdISUpLTE1OT@KAnXDCtcOHxocsw4fDkOG4n0vigqxq4oG@wrbCtv8) (which separates out the two classes).

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>132 129</s> 113 bytes

```r
function(S,P,`!`=utf8ToInt)"[<-"(diag(15),cbind(rep(!"",!"	"),!"
"),1)[-64+!P,-64+!S]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jWCdAJ0Exwba0JM0iJN8zr0RTKdpGV0kjJTMxXcPQVFMnOSkzL0WjKLVAQ1GJkZmVTUkHSHOysSlpAhlMXDx8LKxsHNz8yCRQylAzWtfMRFsxQAdMBcf@T9NQclTSUQASmgrKCrZ2CiVFpalcQFFPkKg3TDQtMacYLOwPEnZGV@wMEvXHUOwKEnZDV@wGEnVFFv0PAA)

Builds the following matrix and extracts `m[S,P]` => 1 if TRUE, else 0.

```r
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15]
 [1,]    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0     0 
 [2,]    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0    0     0
 [3,]    0    0    1    1    1    1    0    1    0     1     1     1     0    1     1
 [4,]    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0    0     0
 [5,]    0    0    0    1    1    1    0    1    0     0     1     0     0    0     1
 [6,]    0    0    0    1    1    1    0    1    0     0     1     0     0    0     1
 [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0     0     0     0     0    0     0
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0     0     0     0     0    0     0
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1     0     0     0     0    0     0
[10,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     1     0     0     0    0     0
[11,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     1     0     0    0     0
[12,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     1     0    0     0
[13,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     1    0     0
[14,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0    1     0
[15,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0    0     1
```

Saved 3 bytes by compressing indexes using `intToUtf8` and replacing this function with `!`. See History for more legible version.

Saved 16 bytes thanks to @Giuseppe!

Comment: do you need `t=` in `rep`?

Comment: @Giuseppe looks like I do not!

Comment: [IDK why this saved so many bytes](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jWCdAJ0Exwba0JM0iJN8zr0RTKdpGV0kjJTMxXcPQVFMnOSkzL0WjKLVAQ1GJkZmVTUkHSHOysSlpAhlMXDx8LKxsHNz8yCRQylAzWtfMRFsxQAdMBcf@T9NQclTSUQASmgrKCrZ2CiVFpalcQFFPkKg3TDQtMacYLOwPEnZGV@wMEvXHUOwKEnZDV@wGEnVFFv0PAA)

Comment: @Giuseppe It totally looks like an esoteric language submission now.

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](http://www.php.net/), 81 bytes

```php
<?list(,$s,$p)=$argv;$A=AB;$C=$E=$F=DEFHKO;$C.=JLN;echo+($p==$s||strpos($$p,$s));
```

To run it:

```
php -n -d error_reporting=0 <filename> <socket> <plug>
```

Example:

```
php -n -d error_reporting=0 socket_plug_compatibility.php F E
```

Or [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DczBCsIwDADQX/GQQ4ubeK9B5mwRFf0EES3bQJqQFE/7duOO7/J4ZLPd/jNpdQ1oA@wRnjJ8A3TYHQL0CBEh4TGm0@W@eIPn6y3k10hrB4wIOs9ahUkdAC@H98HMksUfcZ2oqLXF2vcqi5A8JDNJncqA2z8)

**Notes:**

- To save some bytes, I have used strings without single/double quotations as the string wrapper. Thus, the `error_reporting=0` option is used to not output warnings.
- Input only works with uppercase letters.
- Outputs 1 for compatibility and 0 for non-compatibility.

---

## How?

Every plug is compatible with same socket as itself. There are four special plugs (A, C, E, F) which are compatible with a few more sockets as well. Four string variables with the name of the special plugs are defined to hold list of their extra compatible sockets.

It is checked if input plug and socket are same or if the socket is in the list of compatible sockets for that plug. The latter check is done with the help of [PHP's variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript ES6, <s>66</s> <s>65</s> 64 chars

```
p=>s=>p==s|{A:1,C:14172,E:8788,F:8780}[p]&(1<<parseInt(s,36)-11)
```

Takes capital letters into `p` for plug and `s` for socket, returns falsy (`0`) or truthy (`1`, `2`, `4`, ..., `8192`) value.

#### Test:

```js
f=p=>s=>p==s|{B:1,C:14172,E:8788,F:8780}[p]&(1<<parseInt(s,36)-11)

console.log(`A, A => true
I, K => false
O, C => true
C, O => false
E, F => true
F, E => true`
.split`
`.map(x=>x.match(/(.), (.) => (\w+)/))
.every(([m,p,s,res])=>!!f(s)(p)==eval(res)))
```

Comment: [-1 byte with currying](https://tio.run/##RYrNSsNAFIX38xTTjdyLt6mjYkPoBGpIoLjoA9RChjjRyjQZ5sZYUZ89JovWzfn7zrvpDVfh4Lt5077YodaD1ynr1GvNP9@PiaIsUfdqeUt5Ei/jmIrJbn53fn8FarXyJrDdNB0w3T3gXCkcqrbh1tnIta9QrkmupU5lFz6s2JB8mkptHFuxJZldUEZy@49yksUFFSTzcylFxN4dulKU0dF4OOn0NIaueoMFREhylOkLz5/XuEAUke1t@ALYHckTU7C8R53OZjUwgketbW8cjDMiDn8)

Comment: @AsoneTuhid, thank you, updated. But your link is smth strange and doesn't open.

Comment: It's TIO. Opens for me.

Comment: @AsoneTuhid, `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`

Comment: Did you try removing `https`? Do other TIO links work? I tried on mac (chrome and safari) and android and it works fine...

Comment: @AsoneTuhid, no tio does NOT work with `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`, niether https, nor http.

Comment: That's gotta be a problem with your system then

Comment: @AsoneTuhid, can't open on 2 different computers in different networks.

Comment: How about [this](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/A1q7Y1q7A1ra4ptrJylDH2crQxNDcSMfVysLcwkLHDUQZ1EYXxKppGNrYFCQWFad65pVoFOsYm2nqGhpq/v8PAA)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80470/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-asone-tuhid).

Answer (score 0):

## [Pascal (FPC)](https://www.freepascal.org/), 113 bytes

```pascal
var p,s:char;begin read(p,s);write((p=s)or(pos(p,'CEF')>0)and(pos(s,'DEFHKO')>0)or(pos(p+s,'AB CJ CL CN')>0))end.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcpBCgIxDEDRq2TXBkdx7aCgsYOo6BliW3VAOiEVPX4tBbfvf@Hs@TW/iy/lwwrS5ZV/sva3@BgTaORgq2H/1fEdrZV1xkmtTLmyITcY3CyRU2iUO7N3w@F0bfr/ZpW3O6Aj0Bno0hrGFBalkPsB)

[Test for all values](https://tio.run/##XY1BCsIwEEXX9hSzmwSruHLR0kKNLaJizxCbVAslCZmix48h6MbN8Hnv88dJGuS8Gd0Qwkt6cDkVw1P6Mrvrx2Sy1WgjLCpsEBYL2CMoC1@XJP3Lt58WzZiriFvPnCXmchRth7zecWlUQpTjse1Olz7RX28dcXMAcQZxBXFLDoo9L@OvNDubGLVRZRbPNoQP)

Following the `DEFHKO` train...

`pos(string1,string2)` checks for first occurence of `string1` in `string2` and returns its position in it or 0 if it doesn't exist.