# Maximum sub-array

Tags: code-golf, array

Define the "maximum sub-array" of a given array as "a (consecutive) sub-array that has the biggest sum". Note there's no "non-zero" requirement. Output that sum.

Give a description of your code if possible.

Sample input 1:

```
1 2 3 -4 -5 6 7 -8 9 10 -11 -12 -13 14
```

Sample output 1: `24`

Description 1:
The biggest sum is yielded by cutting `6 7 -8 9 10` out and summing up.

Sample input 2: `-1 -2 -3`
Sample output 2: `0`
Description 2: It's simple :) An empty subarray is the "biggest".

Requirement:

- Don't read anything except stdin, and output should go to stdout.
- Standard loopholes **restrictions** apply.

Ranking: The shortest program wins this [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf).

Comment: *Write a program that's as short as possible.* I would recommend removing this requirement as it requires us to check every possible program in our language and make sure that we're using the shortest.

Comment: Requirement 2 is also unclear. Does it mean libraries? Custom libraries? Outsourcing the program? The latter is already prohibited by the standard loopholes.

Comment: *Don't read anything except stdin, and don't write to anywhere except stdout.* - Why?

Comment: [Very similar](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/4463/20260), possibly a dupe. [Also very similar](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/3059/20260).

Answer (score 10):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>6</s> 4 bytes

```
▲ṁ∫ṫ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9G0TQ93Nj7qWP1w5@r///9HG@oY6Rjr6Jro6JrqmOmY6@ha6FjqGBro6BoaArEREBvrGJrEAgA)

```
      -- implicit input (list) xs  - eg. [-1,2,3]
   ṫ  -- get all tails of xs       -     [[-1,2,3],[2,3],[3],[]]
 ṁ∫   -- map & concat cumsum       -     [0,-1,1,4,0,2,5,0,3,0]
▲     -- get maximum               -     5
```

Comment: [another 4 byter](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9G0TbnnFgf@//8/2lDHSMdYR9dER9dUx0zHXEfXQsdSx9BAR9fQEIiNgNhYx9AkFgA "Husk – Try It Online")

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 61 bytes

```python
a=b=0
for x in eval(input()):a=max(x,a+x);b=max(a,b)
print(b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcdNCoMwEAbQvafIMkO/gGPsnyUnkS4moDTQxiBpiadPxcVbvLTl1xJtreK8a5t5WVVRIarpJ28dYvpmTTSI@0jRBXIq9PBHBJ6atIaYtadaR0YHC9PDnHHBFeaGO7iFYd51Owvun38)

Algorithm stolen from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem).

Comment: [This would be 7 bytes shorter in Python 2](https://tio.run/##HcfNCoQgFIbhfVfhMukTOvY/4ZUMLY6LqEUmYuBcvSPB@yxe/4vH7XTObKxpq/0OIonTlfwTa/lhc3GqE7hJcrXvMKysfDhdFDbnL0Gjg@qhBoyYoGYsoBaKqNBFB@q3Pw) (in case you still use ancient language versions)

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
ẆS€;0Ṁ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hrrbgR01rrA0e7mz4//9/tK6hjq6Rjq5xLAA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 8 bytes

```
eS+0sM.:
```

**[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=eS%2B0sM.%3A&input=%5B-1%2C+-2%2C+-3%5D%0A%5B1%2C+2%2C+3%2C+-4%2C+-5%2C+6%2C+7%2C+-8%2C+9%2C+10%2C+-11%2C+-12%2C+-13%2C+14%5D&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B-1%2C+-2%2C+-3%5D%0A%5B1%2C+2%2C+3%2C+-4%2C+-5%2C+6%2C+7%2C+-8%2C+9%2C+10%2C+-11%2C+-12%2C+-13%2C+14%5D&debug=0)**

---

## How?

```
eS+0sM.:Q - Q is implicit, meaning input. Let's say it's [-1, -2, -3].

      .:  - All contiguous non-empty sublists. We have [[-1], [-2], [-3], [-1, -2], [-2, -3], [-1, -2, -3]].
    sM    - Get the sum of each sublist. [-1, -2, -3, -3, -5, -6]
  +0      - Append a 0 to the sum list. [0, -1, -2, -3, -3, -5, -6]
eS        - Maximum element. S gives us [-6, -5, -3, -3, -2, -1, 0], while e returns 0, the last element.
```

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
ÎŒ0M
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//cN/RSQa@//9H6xrrKOgaAbFhLAA)

-1 thanks to [Adnan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/34388/adnan).

Comment: Same tip as with Okx's answer: `ÎŒOM` should work for 4 bytes.

Comment: @Adnan Thanks I thought there was only a "1 and input" builtin...wait...does it? Shouldn't they be concatenated or something?

Comment: Nope, `M` searches for the largest number in the flattened version of the stack.

Comment: @Adnan ok...this is news to me lol

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 28 bytes

```hs
maximum.scanl((max<*>).(+))0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYrLCsIwFER/ZRYuEr0tvbU@CtYfURchGA0mITQKfr3xdjGHM8w8TXndQ6huutZovj5@YlusSUEpqaf1Wbdqo3Uno0@YkGef3ljB4cKEnrAlNINkR9gTDmJHwkjgTpR5Qb9Afjzc6s@6YB6lNjbnPw)

Comment: won't the maximum always be the last element in the returned  from `scanl`?  so `foldl((max<*>).(+))0` ??

Comment: NVM i see my mistake!

Comment: @matthias If you see the edit history, you'll see that I made the sma mistake. :-)

Answer (score 3):

### C++, <s>197</s> <s>195</s> 187 bytes

-10 bytes thanks to Zacharý

```cpp
#include<vector>
#include<numeric>
int f(std::vector<int>v){int i=0,j,t,r=0;for(;i<v.size();++i)for(j=i;j<v.size();++j){t=std::accumulate(v.begin()+i,v.begin()+j,0);if(t>r)r=t;}return r;}
```

Comment: Can you remove the braces after the first for loop?

Comment: Also, why do you have `l` and `h` anyways?

Comment: @Zacharý l and h was for the start and end index of the sub array

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 54 bytes

```r
a=b=0;for(x in scan()){a=max(x,a+x);b=max(a,b)};cat(b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcdNCoAgEAbQ/XeKlg4lOPaPeJgxCFpkUC2E6OwmLd7inTmLD9649ThVqrZYXYtERfSI3yWp1EidyIU/0gR63SK3CpQZFi10B91jwAg9YQYbaObCFi24yx8)

Algorithm taken from: [Maximum subarray problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem)

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 65 bytes

```r
y=seq(x<-scan());m=0;for(i in y)for(j in y)m=max(m,sum(x[i:j]));m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v9K2OLVQo8JGtzg5MU9DU9M619bAOi2/SCNTITNPoVITxMyCMHNtcxMrNHJ1iktzNSqiM62yYkHK/xtyGXEZc@macOmacplxmXPpWnBZchkacOkaGgKxERAbcxma/AcA)

- Read `x` from stdin.
- Set `y` as index of `x`.
- Iterate twice over all possible nonempty subsets.
- Compare sum of a subset with `m` (initially `m=0`).
- Store maximum value in `m`.
- Print value of `m`.

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 72 bytes

```r
n=length(x<-scan());m=0;for(i in 1:n)for(j in i:n)m=max(m,sum(x[i:j]));m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P882JzUvvSRDo8JGtzg5MU9DU9M619bAOi2/SCNTITNPwdAqTxPEyQJxMoGcXNvcxAqNXJ3i0lyNiuhMq6xYkJb/hlxGXMZcuiZcuqZcZlzmXLoWXJZchgZcuoaGQGwExMZchib/AQ)

- Read `x` from stdin.
- Do a full search over all possible nonempty subsets.
- Compare sum of a subset with `m` (initially `m=0`).
- Store maximum value in `m`.
- Print value of `m`.

## Other unsuccessful ideas

### 58 bytes

```r
Reduce(max,lapply(lapply(seq(x<-scan()),tail,x=x),cumsum))
```

### 63 bytes

```r
Reduce(max,lapply(seq(x<-scan()),function(i)cumsum(tail(x,i))))
```

### 72 bytes

```r
m=matrix(x<-scan(),n<-length(x),n);max(apply(m*lower.tri(m,T),2,cumsum))
```

Comment: `a=b=0` works too. Also, you need to handle printing of the output. When run as a full program (through `source`) this doesn't print anything.

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam, I have added `cat(b)`, but if sourced with `echo=TRUE` it is enough to call `b` for printout.

Comment: I guess there isn't a clear definition on how full programs are run in R. There is rscript in commandline, and source in R itself. But usually flags needed when running a script are included in the bytecount. (I haven't personally managed to get rscript to work nicely with scan, but thats another thing.

Comment: You can use `T=F` instead of `a=b=0` to save two bytes, because `max` will coerce `b` to `numeric`.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to Adnan

```
ÎŒOM
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//cN/RSf6@//9H6xrqKOgaAbFxLAA)

Comment: `ÎŒOM` should work for 4 bytes

Comment: @Adnan Cool, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 24 bytes

```
Max[Tr/@Subsequences@#]&
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <strike>41</strike> 33 bytes

```hs
import Data.List
g=maximum.concatMap(map sum.inits).tails
```

```hs
maximum.(scanl(+)0=<<).scanr(:)[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcxLDoIwGEXhuau4IQ4gpoQCvggswDUggz9QC7GtTYuP1Vvr4AzO5JvJ34VSQXbXoOmz6KfOUz@SUekuK7q2zfL/ubTJ@iG8yKGDJgsnaMIW74ebPBKOEhVYDbbHAUewE87gBRjnsTJWgdcJmgb9xaxCCjdsNC0matYtZo2URNTDd7wpkj6w0dof) thanks to Laikoni

Comment: Anonymous functions are allowed as submission, so you can drop the `g=`. Instead of `concatMap` you can use `=<<` from the list monad: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcxLDoIwGEXhuau4IQ4gpoQCvggswDUggz9QC7GtTYuP1Vvr4AzO5JvJ34VSQXbXoOmz6KfOUz@SUekuK7q2zfL/ubTJ@iG8yKGDJgsnaMIW74ebPBKOEhVYDbbHAUewE87gBRjnsTJWgdcJmgb9xaxCCjdsNC0matYtZo2URNTDd7wpkj6w0dof "Haskell – Try It Online") (33 bytes).

Answer (score 1):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 6 bytes

```
0+ḋΣ¦⌉
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz/30D74Y7uc4sPLXvU0/k/9VHbxP/RuoYKukYKusaxAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, <s>61</s> <s>59</s> 57 bytes

I just started learning Ruby, so this is what I came up with.

```
s=0
p [gets.split.map{|i|s=[j=i.to_i,s+j].max}.max,0].max
```

I first saw this algorithm at the Finnish version of [this unfinished book](https://cses.fi/book.pdf).
It is very well explained at the page 23.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v9jWgKtAITo9taRYr7ggJ7NELzexoLoms6bYNjrLNlOvJD8@U6dYOysWKF5RCyJ0DMDs//8NFYwUjBV0TRR0TRXMFMwVdC0ULBUMDRR0DQ2B2AiIjRUMTQA)

Answer (score 1):

## [k](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_(programming_language)), 14 bytes

```
|/,/+\'(1_)\0,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P82qRl9HXztGXcMwXjPGQOd/moOelYFVwn9DBSMFYwVdEwVdUwUzBXMFXQsFSwVDAwVdQ0MgNgJiYwVDEwA)

```
            0, /prepend a zero (in case we're given all negatives)
       (1_)\   /repeatedly remove the first element, saving each result
    +\'        /cumulative sum over each result, saving each result
  ,/           /flatten (fold concat)
|/             /maximum (fold max)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 11 bytes

```
£ãY mxÃc rw
```

[Try it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=o+NZIG14w2Mgcnc=&input=WzEsIDIsIDMsIC00LCAtNSwgNiwgNywgLTgsIDksIDEwLCAtMTEsIC0xMiwgLTEzLCAxNF0=)

### Explanation

```
£ãY mxÃc rw
m@ãY mx} c rw   // Ungolfed
m@     }        // Map the input array by the following function, with Y=index
  ãY            //   Get all subsections in input array length Y
     mx         //   Sum each subsection
         c rw   // Flatten and get max
```

### Alternate method, 11 bytes

From @ETHproductions; based on [Brute Forces' Husk answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/138700/69583).

```
£sY å+Ãc rw
```

Gets all tails of the input array and cumulatively sums each. Then flattens the array and gets the max.

[Try it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=o3NZIOUrw2Mgcnc=&input=WzEsIDIsIDMsIC00LCAtNSwgNiwgNywgLTgsIDksIDEwLCAtMTEsIC0xMiwgLTEzLCAxNF0=)

Comment: Nice, really nice. I didn't try to implement this challenge when I saw it earlier, but I did think of a different technique and expected it to come out around 15 bytes, so this is great.

Comment: Looking at the Husk answer, there is another efficient way: `£sY å+Ãc rw` (also 11 bytes)

Comment: @ETHproductions Pretty nice, I'll add that to this answer as an alternate method. Could that maybe be improved with some combination of reduce/concat, also like that Husk answer?

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 58 bytes

```javscript
m=Math.max;x=y=>eval("a=b=0;for(k of y)b=m(a=m(a+k,k),b)")
```

Golfed JS implementation of Kadane's algorithm. Made as short as possible.
Open to constructive suggestions!

**What I learnt from this post:** return value of `eval` - when its last statment is a `for` loop - is basically the last value present *inside* the loop. Cool!

**EDIT:** saved four bytes thanks to Justin's and Hermann's suggestions.

Comment: You can avoid the `return` by replacing `{...;return b;}` with `eval("...;b")` since eval returns the last statement.

Comment: @JustinMariner thanks! am always learning something new here :)

Comment: You can remove two more bytes by removing `;b`, since it's returned from the for loop

Comment: @HermanLauenstein Oh, wow, thanks, that's useful!

Answer (score 1):

## J, 12 bytes

```
[:>./@,+/\\.
```

Similar to zgrep's K solution: the scan sum of all suffixes (produces a matrix), raze, take max

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYxBCsIwFET3OcXDTRFL2p/EqoGI97DwF2IQNy669uwxqV0MDDNv5l3yQoqMVJV7vNrh1h@GebZlb3aWLqfY0fON5MWY5@P1YYJERh2CegIqrP5I@BMurESLPRpaM3FCz1yQsfIVFlflkW0ybqfSftWXHw)

#### NOTE

for not too many more bytes, you can get an efficient solution (19 bytes golfed):

```
[: >./ [: ({: - <./)\ +/\
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-h`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 4 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ãx ñ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWg&code=43gg8Q&input=WzEgMiAzIC00IC01IDYgNyAtOCA5IDEwIC0xMSAtMTIgLTEzIDE0XQ)

```
ãx ñ     :Implicit input of array
ã        :Sub-arrays
 x       :Reduced by addition
   ñ     :Sort
         :Implicit output of last element
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>52</s> 51 bytes

```python
f=lambda l:len(l)and max(sum(l),f(l[1:]),f(l[:-1]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYzNCsIwEITvPkWPG5gFN6l/AZ@k9BCpQWETi1bQp48rgoeBGT6@md/L5VZ9a/moqZym1GnUcyV1qU5dSS96PIstZNJB4vgrkWV0rs33a10o0yDwCOAevMEWO/AeB8gaLGLxlgDpTVn9FTZiIHx/Pg)

Comment: This seems to conflict (the otherwise unnecessary) requirement *Don't read anything except stdin, and don't write to anywhere except stdout.*

Answer (score 0):

## Common Lisp, 73 bytes

```
(lambda(a &aux(h 0)(s 0))(dolist(x a s)(setf h(max x(+ h x))s(max s h))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYpRCsIwEESvMl86QQLdtmo9ztYqKbRaTIS9fVw78AZmePdlzlvl9plfBaxcdB0npeKgX2NCE5i9Aqe3m4UGRfbvUZ5IXNVgPCHBQsj7zEjBU48UtOgQe8QzLrgiDrhBGkQRp3U6SP93fw)

Answer (score 0):

## [MY](https://bitbucket.org/zacharyjtaylor/my-language/src/031637f7e827bde8c06b68ddaf39d9773476667a?at=master), 11 bytes

```
⎕35ǵ'ƒ⇹(⍐↵
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y638//9R39QPc@fPMjY9vlX92KRH7Ts1HvVOeNS29f//aEMdIx1jHV0THV1THTMdcx1dCx1LHUMDHV1DQyA2AmJjHUOTWAA) MY is on TIO now! Woohoo!

### How?

- `⎕` = evaluated input
- = subvectors
- `35ǵ'` = `chr(0x53)` (Σ, sum)
- `ƒ` = string as a MY function
- `⇹` = map
- `(` = apply
- `⍐` = maximum
- `↵` = output with a newline.

Sum was fixed (`0` on empty arrays) in order for this to work. Product was also fixed.

Answer (score 0):

## APL, <s>31</s> <s>29</s> 27 bytes

```
⌈/∊∘.{+/W[X/⍨⍺≤X←⍳⍵]}⍨⍳⍴W←⎕
```

[Try it online!](http://tryapl.org/?a=%7B%u2308/%u220A%u2218.%7B+/W%5BX/%u2368%u237A%u2264X%u2190%u2373%u2375%5D%7D%u2368%u2373%u2374W%u2190%u2375%7D1%202%203%20%AF4%20%AF5%206%207%20%AF8%209%2010%20%AF11%20%AF12%20%AF13%2014&run) (modified so it will run on TryAPL)

### How?

- `∊∘.{+/W[X/⍨⍺≤X←⍳⍵]}⍨⍳⍴W←⎕` Generate sums of subvectors
- `⌈/` Maximum

Answer (score 0):

## CJam, 24 bytes

```
q~:A,{)Aew{:+}%}%e_0+:e>
```

Function that takes array of numbers as input.

[Try it Online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q~%3AA%2C%7B)Aew%7B%3A%2B%7D%25%7D%25e_0%2B%3Ae%3E&input=%5B1%202%203%20-4%20-5%206%207%20-8%209%2010%20-11%20-12%20-13%2014%5D)

```
q~:A   e# Store array in 'A' variable
,{)Aew e# Get every possible sub-array of the array
{:+}%  e# Sum every sub array
}e_    e# flatten array of sums
0+     e# Add zero to the array
:e>    e# Return max value in array
```

Answer (score 0):

## Axiom, 127 bytes

```
f(a:List INT):Complex INT==(n:=#a;n=0=>%i;r:=a.1;for i in 1..n repeat for j in i..n repeat(b:=reduce(+,a(i..j));b>r=>(r:=b));r)
```

This would be O(#a^3) Algo; I copy it from the C++ one... results

```
(3) -> f([1,2,3,-4,-5,6,7,-8,9,10,-11,-12,-13,14])
   (3)  24
                                                    Type: Complex Integer
(4) -> f([])
   (4)  %i
                                                    Type: Complex Integer
(5) -> f([-1,-2,3])
   (5)  3
                                                    Type: Complex Integer
```

Answer (score 0):

## Scala, 105 bytes

```
val l=readLine.split(" ").map(_.toInt);print({for{b<-l.indices;a<-0 to b+2}yield l.slice(a,b+1).sum}.max)
```

I didn't find any better way to generate the sub<strike>lists</strike> arrays.

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 242 bytes

```java
import java.util.*;v->{List a=new Stack();for(String x:new Scanner(System.in).nextLine().split(" "))a.add(new Long(x));int r=0,l=a.size(),i=l,j,k,s;for(;i-->0;)for(j=l;--j>1;r=s>r?s:r)for(s=0,k=i;k<j;)s+=(long)a.get(k++);System.out.print(r);}
```

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##LVBdTwIxEHznV0x8auVaOMUvavEPoDEx8cX4UI@CvSu9S7uHqOG3Y0GSTrqdZndnpjYbI9rOhnrR7N26ayOhzpzsyXl5rgCMRng2mW6XoE@Lj2@yomr7QINB5U1KeDQu/A4AF8jGpaksng5PYNO6BSr2erg2XGVul5FPIkOuwhMCNPYbMfudu0QwOtgvvJCpGsbVso3shaILK2ynx4/KhGAz@Z3IrqULXAa7pbkLlnGZOu@IneGMcyPNYsEOLfM2rNiWc5W1Iepx4bWRyf3khsJpX9RFU6TjJuWEmI0VP9S19kqIelaqqNMsPqRpPPIpD2i0U819rXgaaubz@LxtZYk1wyFXJ2VtT7LLwolFrnZ79W@66z98Nn3yfsxmnZM7eXx7h@H/sQVZsdB7f0psty9xgUuICcQVrnEDcYs7lGOIssy4yLhEOfkD)

## 106 bytes without using STDIN/STDOUT requirement.. >.>

```java
a->{int r=0,l=a.length,i=l,j,k,s;for(;i-->0;)for(j=l;--j>1;r=s>r?s:r)for(s=0,k=i;k<j;s+=a[k++]);return r;}
```

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##jU/LboMwELznK/YIYo0wkFdd0y9oLjlGObjESQ3ERLaTqor4droh@YBKHss769nZadRNsf6ibXNox7pT3sOnMvY@AzA2aHdUtYbNo5wIqCO6d3tQsSBuINDxQQVTwwYsSBgVq@6Pr05m2EmVdtqewjca2WGDLXpx7F0kDGNVJuLHu5GdYKypuHDSV@7Dv7mJ9zSglUa0743wiVS7Nkn2sXA6XJ0FJ4ZRPP0v16@O/F9r3HpzgDOFiLbBGXuatn0m2P76oM9pfw3phVqhs5FN68jqH5hi3TnmWCArkc1xgUtkK1wjz5BxTsgJBfJyiKf0/5jHSEaq4qUYZsPIIYcCWAlsDgtYAlvBGngGZEHICQXw8g8)

**Explanation:**

```java
import java.util.*;      // Required import for List, Stack and Scanner

v->{                     // Method with empty unused parameter and no return-type
  List a=new Stack();    //  Create a List
  for(String x:new Scanner(System.in).nextLine().split(" "))
                         //  Loop (1) over the STDIN split by spaces as Strings
    a.add(new Long(x));  //   Add the String converted to a number to the List
                         //  End of loop (1) (implicit / single-line body)
  int r=0,               //  Result-integer
      l=a.size(),        //  Size of the List
      i=l,j,k,           //  Index-integers
      s;                 //  Temp sum-integer
  for(;i-->0;)           //  Loop (2) from `l` down to 0 (inclusive)
    for(j=l;--j>1;       //   Inner loop (3) from `l-1` down to 1 (inclusive)
        r=               //     After every iteration: change `r` to:
          s>r?           //      If the temp-sum is larger than the current `r`:
           s             //       Set `r` to the temp-sum
          :              //      Else:
           r)            //       Leave `r` the same
      for(s=0,           //    Reset the temp-sum to 0
          k=i;k<j;)      //    Inner loop (4) from `i` to `j` (exclusive)
        s+=(long)a.get(k++);
                         //     Add the number at index `k` in the List to this temp-sum
                         //    End of inner loop (4) (implicit / single-line body)
                         //   End of inner loop (3) (implicit / single-line body)
                         //  End of loop (2) (implicit / single-line body)
  System.out.print(r);   //  Print the result to STDOUT
}                        // End of method
```