# ASCII texturing

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art, matrix, binary-matrix

Write a function or a full program that applies an ASCII  texture  to a 2d shape.

**Inputs:** shape, texture, dimensions(optionally).

- Both Shape and Texture can be given by any convenient method (2d matrix, array of strings or string with newlines)
- Shape data have a rectangular shape and contains 2 possible values: [truthy/falsey] binary/integer values (0/1 or n<sub>1</sub>/n<sub>2</sub>) or 2 different characters, just specify which one represent the shape parts [truthy] and which one represent the blank parts [falsey] and be consistent .
- The texture has a square shape only (width ≡ height) and contains printable ASCII characters.
- Optionally you can also pass dimensions of the matrices if needed.

**Output:** the shape with each truthy value substituted with the corresponding texture value (coordinates/indices mod texture size), the blank parts must be substituted with spaces.

- The ratio is always 1:1
- The entire shape must be covered and only the shape.
- No offset, texturing must start at top-left corner (0,0) of the shape data with the origin of the texture also at the top-left corner.

## Examples (using various shape formats in JSON)

**Shape**

```
[[0,0,1,1,0,0],
 [0,1,1,1,1,0],
 [0,1,1,1,1,0],
 [0,0,1,1,0,0]]
```

**Texture**

```
["/\\",
 "\\/"]
```

**Output**

```
["  /\  ",
 " /\/\ ",
 " \/\/ ",
 "  \/  "]
```

---

**Shape**

```
["        xxxxxxxx     ",
 "  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx   ",
 "    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx ",
 "  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
 "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
 "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
 "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
 "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"]
```

**Texture**

```
["[__]",
 "_][_",
 "[__]",
 "_][_"]
```

**Output**

```
["        [__][__]     ",
 "  [__][__][__][__]   ",
 "    [__][__][__][__] ",
 "  [__][__][__][__][__",
 "[__][__][__][__][__][",
 "_][__][__][__][__][__",
 "[__][__][__][__][__][",
 "_][__][__][__][__][__"]
```

---

**Shape**

```
[0,0,0,1]
```

**Texture**

```
["ab",
 "ba"]
```

**Output**

```
["   b"]
```

---

**Shape**

```
["11100001011010",
 "01111010101101",
 "01011011111101"]
```

**Texture**

```
["   ./]| |  / /.",
 "_|_|[]|/|_/\\_|/",
 "_|_|[/|_|_\\/_|.",
 "./_./]|_|//\\/./",
 "_|_|[]|/|_/\\_|/",
 "_|_|[]/ | \\/_|.",
 " /_  /|_|//\\/3/",
 "_|_|[]|/|_/\\_|/",
 "_|_|/ |_|_\\/_|.",
 "./_$/]|_|//\\/./",
 " |_|  |/|_/\\_|/",
 "_|_|[/|_|_\\$_|/",
 "_/  /]|_/ /\\///",
 "_|_/[]|/|/ \\_|/",
 "_|/|[/|_|_ /_||",
 " /_./]|_|  \\/|/"]
```

**Output**

(a surprise for you!)

## Rules

- Input/output can be given by [any convenient method](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/42963).
- You can print it to STDOUT or return it as a function result.
- Either a full program or a function are acceptable.
- Extraneous whitespace are forbidden.
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so all usual golfing rules apply, and the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

---

[Sandbox post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18249/84844)

Answer (score 16):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>20</s> 12 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

-6 bytes through dzaima

Full program. Prompts stdin for:

1. texture as a list of strings
2. number of rows in shape matrix
3. number of columns in shape matrix
4. indices of falsies (to be blanks) in the shape matrix

All the `⎕`s are supposed to be rectangles (they're not [tofu](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/233948/106629)). They symbolise a computer console which here means *prompt for array input via stdin*.

```apl
' '@⎕↑⎕⍴¨⎕⍴⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVIxTsRADOz3FS5OChTE691wHB0tFQ/IRquTkGhOIi3S1gcNCAr@wAN4AU/JR4LXTsIlUkgxa3tndmw5@/Zwcf@0Pzw@9N3b5@1dd3y3pnt5bvsCihsudcePjK/fP196MvZM6EG@1hQYmBqwMJXZmjML9hwYSbASvGQkqZPETmInsZfYC98L33PdTK/XMTb8fmzqyMdpZnbG0dLQCfqFuYWt4JUyNaEh2@lxrXo79ep4WJJMKKQUUso4Agk6Qa@xnU31NwljiU2CBICAZR4jxVQ3CVPEEBOOFc5TDBhT5pQYs4qvMWCJ66oG@eVRBRjZZVD5dRVr5l6buVe@BljpcDNUkK1YxUMFxIGD4oUwqXBQcWcpaYc6F3DTzDHeUGX@2d2wJl0z@cUvRbJbAl0RuZMVuelfc/niFw)

`⎕` prompt for texture as a list of strings; `["/\\","\\/"]`

`⎕⍴` prompt for number of rows in shape matrix (`4`) and use that to cyclically **r**eshape the texture (this gives us enough texture lines); `["/\\","\\/","/\\","\\/"]`

`⎕⍴¨` prompt for number of columns in shape matrix (`6`) and use that to cyclically reshape *each* of the texture lines (this gives us enough characters in each texture line); `["/\\/\\/\\","\\//\\/\\","/\\/\\/\\","\\//\\/\\"]`

`↑` combine the list of lines into a character matrix;
  `["/\/\/\"` 
   `"\//\/\"` 
   `"/\/\/\"` 
   `"\//\/\"]`

`' '@⎕` prompt for indices for blanks (`[[0,0],[0,1],[0,4],[0,5],[1,0],[1,5],[2,0],[2,5],[3,0],[3,1],[3,4],[3,5]]`) and then place blanks **at** those indices;
    `/\`  
   `//\` 
   `//` 
    `/`

Answer (score 9):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
ｍ⤢ｍ⤢；ｎ← ╋
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjREJXUyOTIyJXVGRjREJXUyOTIyJXVGRjFCJXVGRjRFJXUyMTkwJTIwJXUyNTRC,i=MjElMEElNjAlNjAlNjAlMEElNUJfXyU1RCUwQV8lNUQlNUJfJTBBJTVCX18lNUQlMEFfJTVEJTVCXyUwQSU2MCU2MCU2MCUwQTglMEElNjAlNjAlNjAlMEEldTIxOTAldTIxOTAldTIxOTAldTIxOTAldTIxOTAldTIxOTAldTIxOTAldTIxOTAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAldTIxOTAldTIxOTAldTIxOTAldTIxOTAldTIxOTAlMEEldTIxOTAldTIxOTAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAldTIxOTAldTIxOTAldTIxOTAlMEEldTIxOTAldTIxOTAldTIxOTAldTIxOTAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAldTIxOTAlMEEldTIxOTAldTIxOTAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMEElNjAlNjAlNjA_,v=8)

Abusing that the input will be ASCII and so won't contain `←`, but the shape is made of spaces and `←` for easy overlapping and replacement. Alternative [12 bytes](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjREJXUyOTIyJXVGRjREJXUyOTIyJXVGRjFCJTIzJXUyMTkwJXUyNTRCJXVGRjRFJXUyMTkwJTIwJXUyNTRC,i=MjElMEElNjAlNjAlNjAlMEElNUJfXyU1RCUwQV8lNUQlNUJfJTBBJTVCX18lNUQlMEFfJTVEJTVCXyUwQSU2MCU2MCU2MCUwQTglMEElNjAlNjAlNjAlMEElMjMlMjMlMjMlMjMlMjMlMjMlMjMlMjMlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjMlMjMlMjMlMjMlMjMlMEElMjMlMjMlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjMlMjMlMjMlMEElMjMlMjMlMjMlMjMlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjMlMEElMjMlMjMlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMEElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMEElNjAlNjAlNjA_,v=8) taking shape as space and `#`.

Answer (score 6):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 10 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ËmÈ?VgEY:S
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=y23IP1ZnRVk6Uw&footer=bXEgcVI&input=W1swLDAsMSwxLDAsMF0sCiBbMCwxLDEsMSwxLDBdLAogWzAsMSwxLDEsMSwwXSwKIFswLDAsMSwxLDAsMF1dLApbIi9cIiwKICJcLyJd)

```
ËmÈ?VgEY:S       U = shape as 2d array, V = texture as list of lines
Ë                Map each row, define E as row number
 mÈ                Map each element in these rows, define Y as element number
   ?                 Is the value a 1?
    VgEY               Get the character at texture[E,Y]
        :S           Else return a space if the value is a 0
```

Comment: You don't need the space before the `:`

Comment: @Shaggy Somehow I missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 32 bytes

```
4 :'y}'' '',:x({.@]$($"1~{:))$y'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZFNS8NAEIbv@yteysIkUGeybfAQCQiCJ09e3bAHsYgXD@nB0tG/Hicfli2GsGFe5snDG/Zj2DAd0DYgbFGhsXPDeHh@ehxqNHT6JgLRtvkqznzf@cJvws@5KUt/oqF07tjyDjtPEqOQ61tGjVt4s1QI9lSX6S/l84Vxb6/vnzjigN7NM5FzPcy3R6hNmH9UTVNY3tfS8G@bp3BFju1RdHecduX475UDwNIpFBAIu6RJXzoVTRKTypwtaYqSlB1LGnlbSRSWdb4T8808JJl54ffrvNG53@f@cQWs9vFTFtMbb@WjyLSXyS9YeFl4a6I69pn7wwravswuYvgF)

Some notes:

- This was a rare case where I got a shorter solution with an explicit, rather than tacit, verb.
- I wanted a solution that didn't prompt for input (ie, didn't want to just translate Adam's excellent APL solution into J).

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <del>51</del> 49 bytes

- The texture and shape are provided in the format used by the first example.
- This works even if the texture isn't square or contains unprintables.
- Dimensions do not need to be passed.
- -2 bytes by abbreviating `zipWith` to `z`.

```hs
f=z(z(%)).cycle.map cycle
z=zipWith
_%0=' '
x%_=x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##1VRNj4IwEL33V7wQjZCQjmTPnPa6e9rDHkrToMFo/IgRTJT0v7MDVT50V71uJtDy@ubNtNNhmebrbLOpiiwv3tM8yxFD@QLKoyTxQgF4SUKe5plS03AaRmw81gCU@2ygP4HORQdho6yM0U7aaGXc7Abr4vUturF2ZRjrkd3QX3J5Xb0xR4/C6D/SrzVKZ64as3RQi44AQJK2sACBJC7Fs8Yqbckavj7GUg9lzBq@S8ZKh0oytQKzmEuSnipo4mh9BZDh6FeFt6cK7H@fw@g@h5oGPNrFqEOJU2AFPgRWoI5LTQ6EgQJdFDhza9Huwp0D6s3Za7MNr3jU9tFvvdZ7mndH6Lz6PVCXUUALsU1XO@74bbr/NPDdsD8WX8XhYweJ425@PBzOWARofxDVIi790h8HgZyf55tMsheamSjjcrX/XhVLYcbTeIKJOI1NfKqqHw)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
εNUεiXèNèëð
```

Port of [*@EmbodimentOfIgnorance*'s Japt answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/195899/52210), so make sure to upvote him!

Inputs as defined in the first format of the challenge. Output as a character-matrix.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3Fa/0HNbMyMOr/A7vOLw6sMb/sd6Hdr9PzraQMdAxxAIgXSsTjSEDeZj4SFUxnJFK@nHxCjpKMXE6CvFAgA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##1ZOxTsMwEIZ3nuIUdbRyjWBnY2DoBgI51imRGDoxsF7epxILS7t0a/a@UvgdO4mblqorOiWOz/93d47Pn19Vvf7oHp5eu@N29XLcrt/f2s2q3bTf7U/XNM3zYW8Ou8fOZlyWmcnKkjN3Z@3SLE0Bw@iMDd/9/MJsUoLMrIhDIHFWMKSzIW5qxczGlRj5XHGRGNU3ETfH7u1kx/9J7U@jqvH36yr598FPRDk7JSVi4twfkYpap6yCThDlwQWHCtpC1KtyFs9hHSrO@QroGNFHkFiQagDvr4DAZhkXs4xeQPRnqYvoYiQEiP0B5KjiPiPTBHIEUaFqqDRskXz1Gu7DaXcWY8@f3Yjk6d9xddKnnYuz@AU). (Footer will pretty-print the character-matrix, feel free to remove it to see the actual output.)

**Explanation:**

```python
ε          # Map over the rows of the (implicit) integer-matrix:
 NU        #  Push the map-index, and then pop and store it in variable `X`
   ε       #  Inner map over the cells of the current row:
    i      #   If the value of the current cell is a 1:
     Xè    #    Use variable `X` to index into the (implicit) input-list of strings,
           #    with automatic wraparound
       Nè  #    And then use the inner map index to index into this string
    ë      #   Else:
     ð     #    Push a space instead
```

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 19 bytes

```
]]&' '"+]g"1~g=:$~#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/Y2PV1BXUlbRj05UM69JtrVTqlP9r/i/OSCxIBWnQ1TMAKjYEQiCtA2GBeShsKyRFXCWpFSWlRWDd6vp66jpW6jH66nDRNAWI2dEKqckZ@Qo@bijqo3Vj1XXUY6N1Qdp0Y6Px6AMA)

Dyadic train. Left argument is texture, right argument is shape, 1 is blank, 0 is fill.

#### How it works

I extended [the dyadic `&` trick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/195891/78410) to the "If" usage of `^:`, i.e. boolean repetition amount. Also, an assignment `=:` can group the part of the train on its right, saving a pair of parens.

```
]]&' '"+]g"1~g=:$~#  Left argument: texture, Right argument: shape
                $~#  Repeat the texture's rows to fit the shape's rows
             g=:     Assign this sub-function to g
        ]g"1~        Use g to do the same on columns
]     "+             For each cell on the texture and shape,
 ]&' '                 Replace the texture's cell with ' ' if shape's cell is 1
                       Keep the texture if shape's cell is 0
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 68 bytes

```julia
f(s,t,n,Y,X)=[t[y,x] ? s[mod1(y,n),mod1(x,n)] : ' ' for y=1:Y,x=1:X]
```

Takes the shape as a 2d array of characters, the pattern as a array of Bools, and the dimensions (because `length` is long). Returns a character array via array comprehension.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY/RasMwDEXf@xUifYgNYo1D1odAN9hXtLgeuIlDXVw72O5Ixv49cwNZ@zJdEEdwdZEuN6MlG6apIwEjWjzgnu545CMOAt4h8KtrGRnRUpxpSCSghjypcx7GHasPOKS@F1OrQ09k2u@9ttFY0nvXEskHrAWls38AbYHVQX8rIpGlrPVshuYsvWyi8iC9lyO4r4TXm4m6NwqMtiqsOuJVOMteEZ5vcsyPx6VtcoEllhQ/nDMvJHppQ@@CeiwUWCBLKnChZXrmP49AssWKpkq5FW4p/LzB/b/V8lu2zj5fC/p0VOOMUU0kmTydZEYfB/EC7mICoUzx1b9h0y8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 16 bytes

```
Ｆθ«ＦΣιＧ→¹η¿›0ι⸿→
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYxBCsIwFETXeoohqwRqk2z1AK4E0WVTQpFoCzXBWAvi9@wxRv9mZh5/5tR38RS6MaVziOA3gddyUezxceWDENiH8XkJnq8Pw6WfKugKvdgsF8MZfBtdN7nImWIVynMc/MSZiUxs4Ma7wy7M7t/NrXdKDdNaq3xaZdXK@KzF/cA3F6N/OC8zALVsCQRIyBrGW7LUtCTJSmMsyT/Jmawx0lLN2rSaxw8) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as newline-delimited strings. Explanation:

```
Ｆθ«
```

Loop over the shape.

```
ＦΣι
```

If the value is a `1`...

```
Ｇ→¹η
```

... then draw a 1x1 polygon filled using the template. Conveniently in Charcoal the fill is always relative to the origin of the canvas. Unfortunately Charcoal can't draw zero-sized polygons or Oblongs of sides less than 2, otherwise I could save a couple of bytes here.

```
¿›0ι
```

If this is a newline...

```
⸿
```

... then move to the start of the next line of the canvas...

```
→
```

... otherwise move forward on the current line.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 bytes

```
JṁJ}ị⁸ṁ"⁹a@o⁶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##1VO9TsMwEN79FKcoG1GuFiNCYu4bVI5lpRJLVYkZ6ZAaFgZeAWYW5ogKiSF9kvpFwuXSOC4ttCu6wXefv8@ff86L2@Xyvm2n23U1fdh@Pvvqg9PEV@vy5s5XdTvzj@8Lv3pp6oum9qvXK8mv@3zzhrNUbZ6EU301dVO3rVEcCRZFkilIigITmyljJtkk0xw8cg2mrwT5pR75VjEkyxrnrKzrrHGS7CPBKg79I8JMxz5GOCoYyGcJzl1ZoiPrTP8v8vgm5Vzuf17Gtx8TACBHS0AACJhD/1zkyFhCctwqjnAEGSLHfeMoFzBH18mZw0zM8YTcIhtFckDHvoP88oScxQfu6YF7RwL4Y/NpAJHNWc4HZzkGJoo7QizHnZx3TATD5vuzQ3ck2v2l/TbW4aeExhsbV@8ThulREXe5PJqy3w)

A dyadic link taking a list of Jelly strings for the texture as its left argument and an integer matrix for the shape as its right argument. Returns a list of Jelly strings.

Answer (score 2):

## [Icon](https://github.com/gtownsend/icon), <s>100</s> 97 bytes

```
procedure f(t,s)
i:=0&r:=|!t\*s&i+:=1&j:=0&c:=|!r\*!s&s[i,j+:=1]:=[" ",c][s[i,j]]&\z
return s
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vVPBboMwDD3DV7hRhaBDeGQ3JL4kRFFLqUSl0SnQTZvy750T0pZ2dNppOeHnx7P9nLT1oTud3vShbrZH3cAuHtI@CduifI50UZrFUK36qH0qyjzaW7C2oK5Wiz7qRZvubUYWpWDA0loKh0kZVV@hboaj7qAPm247qfC6brs4CYFO897oT/jQ7dBAvNjFgmFVsZRVFTKZhkEgWJ5znueMAgiAUUChjX4EI08mSXgv7ZQDJpSSjhwwJYXyn/eoK@vqjof74wJPvKKT7CU3k334Hx2f4/y/cs6iWY/YekPmb9ZkgjOAP7aTEZahNGAAEDDzW1BGGSENGkWLVAanMIFG0WaVObMzVFaDeMTGDP8gIpEq3ogAKmrhLPLyBxGSmOlkOdOJJQL8Os5yAiM1QiLkB4nghI2uE4RbEfQiNIEx12lGS8BOaS7PwN9Abm/53QPgHr2ALhov3rhB@/6@AQ)

Uses `1` for spaces and `2` for textured in shape data.

### Explanation:

```
procedure f(t,s)                   ; t - texture, s - shape data
    i:=0 &                         ; i is the row index
    r:=|!t\*s &                    ; repeats the rows of the texture as many times as the rows of the shape data  
    i+:=1 &                        ; next row
    j:=0 &                         ; j is the column index; reset to start
    c:=|!r\*!s &                   ; repeats the characters of each row of the texture as many times as the row of the shape 
    s[i,j+:=1]:=[" ",c][s[i,j]] &  ; modify the shape data ot " " or to texture
    \z                             ; z is not declared and thus causes Icon to backtrack 
    return s                       ; return the modified shape data
end
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>97</s> <s>94</s> 86 bytes

```python
lambda S,P,w:[''.join([' ',P[j%w][i%w]][v]for i,v in E(s))for j,s in E(S)]
E=enumerate
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVPBbqMwEL3zFSOrK0CyGAycVuLYuyWOxrJIN9EStaRKsm1W8r9nx2OasGo2Pa2RsOfNe57xM7z@Pv7cTdV50/bn5@Fl9WOATmr5/t2kabHdjVNmUkilNttv79aM9LLmzW52exjlG4wTPGaHPA/xVh5i3OU2eWzX06@X9X44rs@dghaMKWUpFT00W5mYGDBwM7ySbZJo3kJg3wsJou9RENhVvO84HbOntk1PKbfxFJo4WAhrbsgImMdpHhwImYC4YovcnLmR@4eGBmdOp/@fITc0n1sY5ywTnTWOF38jwaH64jzZGaQMiGEVbFwNzGmuLi4NXPinlCppqJJmVXIFWnIQsRnitYoZbrRp2fwCrQcPgIBF9NB554316B1dqfN4BQnyji7Y@YLBAl2QE4eYWOAXcotUaCEHdFT3Q15/ISfxp@oPn6oHEsCd5h8uIFJxktPBSY4XJnJ1hKUcZzl17D18NB/PDuFInj/61z3dFKT9NP@dm6xTUiv5vJ4yrfI8j4xbvErqKvKqu7xa6jry6ru8Ruom8poL7/wH)

3 bytes thx to [frank](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/90146/frank)

Takes the shape as `S`, a list list of `0/1`;the texture `P` as a list of strings; and `w` as the width/height of `P`. Returns a list of strings.

Comment: Texture is guaranteed to be square so you can just do `i%len(P)`

Comment: @frank - ah thanks, I missed that!

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 65 bytes

```ruby
->s,p,w,h{s.zip(p*h).map{|a,b|a.zip(b*w).map{|x,y|x>0?y:' '}*''}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZhvzX9euWKdAp1wno7pYryqzQKNAK0NTLzexoLomUSepJhEslqRVDhWr0KmsqbAzsK@0UldQr9VSV6@t/V9QWlKskBYdHW2gY6BjCIRAOlYnGsIG87HwECqBXCX9mBglHQWlmBh9pViQRRpqVskZiUXFmjomOmax/wE)

**Input**: Matrix of 0 and 1, texture as 2d array of characters, size of the matrix (width and height).

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 9 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ËmÈù1VgEY
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&header=bcs/UDpT&code=y23I%2bTFWZ0VZ&footer=Vm1xIHFS&input=W1swLDAsMSwxLDAsMF0sCiBbMCwxLDEsMSwxLDBdLAogWzAsMSwxLDEsMSwwXSwKIFswLDAsMSwxLDAsMF1dLApbIi9cIiwKICJcLyJd)