# Rotate a number

Tags: code-golf, number

Given a positive number `n`, rotate its base-10 digits `m` positions rightward. That is, output the result of `m` steps of moving the last digit to the start. The rotation count `m` will be a non-negative integer.

You should remove leading zeroes in the final result, but not in any of the intermediate steps. For example, for the test case `100,2 => 1`, we first rotate to `010`, then to `001`, then finally drop the leading zeroes to get `1`.

### Tests

```
n,m => Output

123,1 => 312
123,2 => 231
123,3 => 123
123,4 => 312
1,637 => 1
10,1 => 1
100,2 => 1
10,2 => 10 
110,2 => 101
123,0 => 123
9998,2 => 9899
```

Comment: I've edited the post (i.e. added some formatting/CGCC terms) to help make it even more understandable. Nice first challenge!

Comment: The test cases suggest this loops around for big n, which isn't clear from the text.

Comment: You should indicate in the text that the rotation is to the right

Comment: @Shaggy Hm I guess "moving the last digit to the start" is clear enough

Comment: From the test cases, it seems the input number can be base 4 or any higher base, to handle digits up to 3?  Power-of-2 bases are much more efficient and convenient to work with in binary computers, e.g. hardware rotate instructions, and bit-shifts.  e.g. x86 `add ecx,ecx` / `ror eax, cl` rotates by `n` 2-bit digits, in 4 bytes of machine code.  Nothing in the question actually says you have to rotate base-10 digits, which would be inconvenient if you get input as an `int` or something.  But I suspect you meant that?

Comment: (It's actually not as easy as `ror`, that wouldn't ignore leading 0s in the 32-bit integer like this question requires.  So some kind of `bsr` to find the highest non-zero digit in base 4, 8, or 16, and manual shifts maybe to implement the rotate.  Still easier than base 10 I think.)

Comment: `8 -> ∞` Am I doing it right?

Answer (score 14):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-N`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 2 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Takes `m` as a string and `V=n` as an integer or string, outputs an integer.
Prepend `s` or `ì` for +1 byte if we *have* to take both as integers.

```
éV
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LU4&code=6VY&input=IjEyMCIKMQ)

Comment: Gorgeous!......

Comment: @Lonely, I think the word you're looking for is "trivial"!

Answer (score 10):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 51 bytes

```r
function(n,m,p=10^nchar(n))sum(n*p^(0:m))%/%10^m%%p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc5RCoMwDAbg950iMArtKCxtx4SBl9gBBCfV@dBUant@p1O021v4kp/8YQo@1tGWU5uoib0nTtLJoVRYUfOuAychxuQ4XYaK48MJwa5sXjrGhi3LlTZSCTiDUfqUmV5MG5WbWWwecrv9Z@XdFN87eKUInbcj@HnwLTyBkrOhbyDU1Nk9gWuB4xXi@j6TDRB2OuynI24dpw8)

Numeric solution (that fails for combinations of n & m that cause it to exceed R's numeric range): chains the digits of n, m times (so: `123` => `123123123123` for m=4) and then calculates DIV 10^m (so: `12312312` for m=4) MOD 10^digits(n) (so: `312`).

---

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>61</s>  53 bytes

*Edit: -8 bytes thanks to Giuseppe*

```r
function(n,m,N=nchar(n),M=10^(m%%N))n%%M*10^N/M+n%/%M
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc7NCsIwDAfwu09RkECrgTWt6KmP0D6CMIaih2VQ6vPXzY4ZvSU//vnINU@lL7dQ7y8eynNizThiCjw8@qzZYAxkr3oESMYwQDzMberikaGDuE5rch7JqL3y5HbC3GLOkzS/2FxIO/3P4tlfPrlNbDsgwLb1MtLAqo2@9vODXX@obw)

<s>Text-based function that</s> Rotates by combining the two parts of the number together, so does not go out of numeric range: puts the last (m MOD digits(n)) digits of n first, followed by the other digits of n.

Comment: [53 bytes](https://tio.run/##Xc7NCsIwDAfwu09RkECrgTWt6KmP0D6CMIaih2VQ6vPXzY4ZvSU//vnINU@lL7dQ7y8eynNizThiCjw8@qzZYAxkr3oESMYwQDzMberikaGDuE5rch7JqL3y5HbC3GLOkzS/2FxIO/3P4tlfPrlNbDsgwLb1MtLAqo2@9vODXX@obw) for the second one, no need for text functions to stay in R's range (for the given test cases, anyway)

Comment: Thanks Giuseppe, that's very nice.

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>61</s> 57 bytes

```python
i=input
n=i()
k=int(i())%len(n)
print(int(n[-k:]+n[:-k]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P9M2M6@gtIQrzzZTQ5MrG8gr0QCyNFVzUvM08jS5CorAIkCcF62bbRWrnRdtpZsdq6n5/7@hgQGXEQA)

Uses string slicing to move the last k digits at the beginning and converts it to an integer to remove the leading zeroes.

*-4 bytes thanks to Lyxal*

Comment: [57 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P9M2M6@gtIQrzzZTQ5MrG8gr0QCyNFVzUvM08jS5CorAIkCcF62bbRWrnRdtpZsdq6n5/7@hgQGXEQA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-pl`, 26 bytes

```perl
eval'$_=chop.$_;'x<>;$_|=0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z@1LDFHXSXeNjkjv0BPJd5avcLGzlolvsbW4P9/QyNjLkMuEGkEJoE8AwMQG0ga/8svKMnMzyv@r1uQAwA)

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
(._ï
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fQy/@8Pr//424DA0MDAE)

### Explanation

```
(._ï
(     : get negative of m
 ._   : rotate n left negative m times
   ï  : remove leading zeros
```

Comment: I may be misremembering but doesn't 05AB1E also have a rotate right built-in, to save you a byte on the negation?

Comment: @Shaggy, Pretty new to 05AB1E. I could not find a built-in to rotate right m units in the [wiki](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), though there was a built-in to rotate right 1 unit (`Á`).

Comment: That might've been what I was thinking of. Would a loop using that be shorter?

Comment: @Shaggy this would be the same length: `EÁ}ï`. At least that is the best I can come up with. It would be shorter if we didn't need to remove leading zeroes (just `EÁ`).

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 39 bytes

```python
lambda n,m:int(((n*m)[-m:]+n)[:len(n)])
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSFPJ9cqM69EQ0MjTytXM1o31ypWO08z2ionNU8jTzNW839BEUg6TUPdwtzM1MTY0sDQSF1HwdBYU/M/AA)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##VY/RaoUwDIbvfYrgjc2WgbVjG4JP4rzotGWCraX2HLYVn921yi5GEvIn@QKJ@w6fqxVvzh@6ez8WaT4mCZZMO9vAGLMPBvsn0w6PFvt2UZZZHPDQq08QGAL15dQY1ASzhZ/ZMcYbQf@CeJ28PlOORiAxTg0JeqYX8UpZZ6tTX/CkBD83s@aX5e2zidgWMK6Tgg50qVn0ynm2BZ/uwp2i2bEsQI7hJpeEqLtcWMaxAOfzS7qMud7TMF7YDi3EvtJyXiqqnNy2auj/3uq6Cxr2Eo9f).

#### How?

Rotating `n` right by `m` is the same as rotating `n` right by `m` modulo length `n` (`m%len(n)`), which is the concatenation of the last `m%len(n)` digits with the first `len(n)-m%len(n)` digits.

A simple slice would give us

```python
lambda n,m:int(n[-m%len(n):]+n[:-m%len(n)])
```

for 43 bytes. To remove the need for the repeated `-m%` we can instead concatenate the last `m%len(n)` digits with all the digits of `n` and ***then*** take the first `len(n)` digits. This is

```python
lambda n,m:int((n[-m%len(n):]+n)[:len(n)])
```

for 42 bytes. The `n[-m%len(n):]` can then be replaced with taking the rightmost `m` digits of `m` `n`s concatenated together, `(n*m)[-m:]` giving us the 39 byte solution.

Answer (score 5):

## [Taxi], <s>1698</s> 1678 bytes

<sup>No need to wrap single-byte plan names in quote marks. 0.6% byte reduction!</sup>

```
Go to Post Office:w 1 l 1 r 1 l.Pickup a passenger going to Chop Suey.Pickup a passenger going to The Babelfishery.Go to The Babelfishery:s 1 l 1 r.Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.1 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.Go to Starchild Numerology:n 1 l 1 l 1 l 2 l. Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.Go to Addition Alley:w 1 r 3 r 1 r 1 r.Pickup a passenger going to The Underground.Go to Chop Suey:n 1 r 2 r.[1]Switch to plan 2 if no one is waiting.Pickup a passenger going to Narrow Path Park.Go to Narrow Path Park:n 1 l 1 r 1 l.Go to Chop Suey:e 1 r 1 l 1 r.Switch to plan 1.[2]Go to Narrow Path Park:n 1 l 1 r 1 l.Switch to plan 3 if no one is waiting.Pickup a passenger going to Chop Suey.Go to Chop Suey:e 1 r 1 l 1 r.Switch to plan 2.[3]Go to Chop Suey:e 1 r 1 l 1 r.[a]Go to The Underground:s 1 r 1 l.Switch to plan b if no one is waiting.Pickup a passenger going to The Underground.Go to Fueler Up:s.Go to Chop Suey:n 3 r 1 l.Pickup a passenger going to Chop Suey.Switch to plan a.[b]Go to Chop Suey:n 2 r 1 l.[4]Switch to plan 5 if no one is waiting.Pickup a passenger going to Narrow Path Park.Go to Narrow Path Park:n 1 l 1 r 1 l.Go to Chop Suey:e 1 r 1 l 1 r.Switch to plan 4.[5]Go to Narrow Path Park:n 1 l 1 r 1 l.[c]Switch to plan d if no one is waiting.Pickup a passenger going to KonKat's.Go to KonKat's:e 1 r.Pickup a passenger going to KonKat's.Go to Narrow Path Park:n 2 l.Switch to plan c.[d]Go to KonKat's:e 1 r.Pickup a passenger going to The Babelfishery.Go to The Babelfishery:s.Pickup a passenger going to The Babelfishery.Go to KonKat's:n.Go to The Babelfishery:s.Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.Go to Post Office:n 1 l 1 r.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zVU9b4MwEN37K27rZglIFra0UjtESiOlmSwGBwxYcW1kjGh@PTWfSR2Uxpk6AOLse@/d3QNr8s2a5l2ClrCVpYaPNGUxDWvwgJtLtU@0ZfGxKoBAQcqSiowqyCQTWZv1mssCdhU93dz1mVN4IQfKU1bmVJ1QT2mHw3LkvYm2ShKmmRSw4twQe8BKqIkJmWWiYaeJinPGE9hUX1RJLrORcG4pFANpf/mmYHBg74F/B7v@KQi6/qk/62nbsBcJVZmSlUgGyKmznUBlhCmEvWhXMx3n7YaCE2GiLAUhQQp60YabdBuilKxhS3Rubuo48NnhqS@9CWxRdFzpyrNUeQj70V2wVmLgXs7ZgU4SfYSD6HYGJtHZpxcD6mw6K//gLn9@@G8V5WbXvgjLGTsETh@mpZEgfIiuMf0BEy9siy3/pcUWCC/vsxiO7YoS94rWUqyJfh6nMb72Gl0yZ8T610aKEU4iZ6q7f7OPoEw6xGOwF@cLuj5xppGhpvH84Mn7AQ)

I chose to get fired rather than sacrifice the bytes required to return to the garage at the end. I have checked both very long inputs and very long rotations and the net gain is positive so you never run out of gas.

---

Formatted for legibility and with comments:

```
[ Pick up the inputs, add 1 to the second, and chop the first into pieces. ]
Go to Post Office:w 1 l 1 r 1 l.
Pickup a passenger going to Chop Suey.
Pickup a passenger going to The Babelfishery.
Go to The Babelfishery:s 1 l 1 r.
Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.
1 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.
Go to Starchild Numerology:n 1 l 1 l 1 l 2 l. 
Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.
Go to Addition Alley:w 1 r 3 r 1 r 1 r.
Pickup a passenger going to The Underground.
Go to Chop Suey:n 1 r 2 r.

[ Reverse the order the charaters are stored in so we can right-shift instead of left-shift. ]
[1]
Switch to plan 2 if no one is waiting.
Pickup a passenger going to Narrow Path Park.
Go to Narrow Path Park:n 1 l 1 r 1 l.
Go to Chop Suey:e 1 r 1 l 1 r.
Switch to plan 1.
[2]
Go to Narrow Path Park:n 1 l 1 r 1 l.
Switch to plan 3 if no one is waiting.
Pickup a passenger going to Chop Suey.
Go to Chop Suey:e 1 r 1 l 1 r.
Switch to plan 2.
[3]
Go to Chop Suey:e 1 r 1 l 1 r.

[ Loop the required times, rotating the passengers at Chop Suey each time. ]
[a]
Go to The Underground:s 1 r 1 l.
Switch to plan b if no one is waiting.
Pickup a passenger going to The Underground.
Go to Fueler Up:s.
Go to Chop Suey:n 3 r 1 l.
Pickup a passenger going to Chop Suey.
Switch to plan a.
[b]
Go to Chop Suey:n 2 r 1 l.

[ Reverse the character order again. ]
[4]
Switch to plan 5 if no one is waiting.
Pickup a passenger going to Narrow Path Park.
Go to Narrow Path Park:n 1 l 1 r 1 l.
Go to Chop Suey:e 1 r 1 l 1 r.
Switch to plan 4.
[5]
Go to Narrow Path Park:n 1 l 1 r 1 l.

[ Concatenate the passengers at Narrow Path Park. ]
[c]
Switch to plan d if no one is waiting.
Pickup a passenger going to KonKat's.
Go to KonKat's:e 1 r.
Pickup a passenger going to KonKat's.
Go to Narrow Path Park:n 2 l.
Switch to plan c.

[ Convert to a number to remove leading zeros and then back to a string so the Post Office can handle it. ]
[d]
Go to KonKat's:e 1 r.
Pickup a passenger going to The Babelfishery.
Go to The Babelfishery:s.
Pickup a passenger going to The Babelfishery.
Go to KonKat's:n.
Go to The Babelfishery:s.
Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.
Go to Post Office:n 1 l 1 r.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zVY9c9swDN31K7B1aX0nOVm8pblrh/RSX9NMPg2wCEm8yKRKUnHbP@@ClKVTZdWxNXWQLQPE18MDaIc/5eGwgbXMXqCpwZUEUtWNs@8BhYAYnA5CS5lWgoVKQFbq9mQujXV8ns/UkjKyC0ijz9rbrDVrvua5zGi1ZzcVP8Z/LyIfi0Mh1GgtqYIMFFqqwpvde9dPDf06f@w7B/@IW6pyaUsyfLqNOpavbBf6vL87IaSTWsFdVfnYMUgLe2QZ69HBk0OTlbIS8NjsyOhKF33MKd1KHeO2T8Jlw1UJtK7/lgYcDSwDjubtojwYz0qQKYxulOic9hCHJA0nx36iDXyjVzKWQmO1YbPwlpVo0LEC0DALnDYkuONgNexZiwqMLEr3wZYy91SwjlCAzqGi/Cj1pNjEafS0ly4rfQp1xXYJyByUBq1ogPb5kh7RGL2HNbqSP8xLV9NY3uN/pNy4cupULYqjzOJFtEnSC12PbJczqhqQ/rpEE050mb5lxL39oo8Ta@hHI30LndwRz7jRDgPJvbJPzXrO9/6A0Mdkg9BJTAfDNuBXmLVpULYzQPkHez81VPGx53plpwi9vHLJjBJFBnSbTvhNOr@jQQnjkfF8HEcGC5QqwHRzQvjb/5bwN1z27aWEZwTutcp4KSh@JohzkrOHIzuBQ8yA40GrB3Tv@tZ3v9v6rrOdqDOZ4G7WVcxNd16KoJrd1q9HzeO006/Euw6Fj/Kb178NVySjwrRHvlSDhXXG6217lw7uxrBBS7aoGIR2U4p0RnGXX4jz/PS5qLmeB0UvJv4j9CRbHA5xsoziPw)

Answer (score 4):

## APL+WIN, <s>8</s> 7 bytes

Prompts for n as integer and m as string:

```
⍎(-⎕)⌽⎕
```

[Try it online! Courtesy of Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcjzra0/4/6u3T0AWKaT7q2Quk/gMF/6dxqRsaGatzGXLBWEZwljGcZQJmqXOZGZuDWQYwDQYGMA1wBoIF0mnAxQUA)

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 36 bytes

Expects `(m)(n)`, where `n` is a string and `m` is either a string or an integer.

```javascript
m=>g=n=>m--?g(n%10+n.slice(0,-1)):+n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY/RCsIgFIbv9xTehMpy8@goCFzPMszJYtPI6PVNgmCbq@4OfN/5z3@u3bML@j7cHsz5i4m9ipNqrXKqnRg7W@J2wEtXhXHQhvA9A0pPpYvau@BHU43ekp4gBJRgEBJTiuoaSRDF2hALQ0jIDLkw0pQZzZ8rB3mkScPwySg2eibMv/J3S/6Tz/c52k6YGXkGX/8ZXw)

Answer (score 4):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 4 bytes

```
v.>z
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/v0zPrur/f2MuQ3MjSwA)

## Explanation

```
v.>zQ
    Q  : first line of input evaluated 
   z   : second line of input as string
 .>    : cyclically rotate second line right by number in first line
v      : evaluate to remove leading 0s
```

Comment: Always happy to see people using Pyth.

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 3 bytes

```
YSU
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/PzI49P9/JUMDQyNjJS4TAA)

Takes `n` as a string and `m` as an integer.

#### Explanation

```
YS   % Shift first input second input number of times
  U  % Convert to integer to remove leading 0s
```

---

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 5 bytes

```
ViYSU
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/PywzMjj0/39DA0MjYy4TAA)

This answer takes both the inputs as integers.

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 9 bytes

```
ＩＩ⭆θ§θ⁻κη
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sRhKBJcABdJ9Ews0CnUUHEs881JSK0BM38y80mKNbB2FDE0wsP7/39DAgMvkv25ZDgA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
   θ        Input `n` as a string
  ⭆         Map over characters and join
       κ    Current index
      ⁻     Subtract
        η   Input `m`
    §       Cyclically indexed into
     θ      Input `n` as a string
 Ｉ          Cast to integer
Ｉ           Cast to string
            Implicitly print
```

Conveniently if you try to Subtract an integer and a string then the string gets cast to integer.

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/)`-lm`, <sup><s>65</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>56</s></sup> 55 bytes

Saved a byte thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!!!

```c
e;f(n,m){for(e=log10(n);m--;)n=n%10*exp10(e)+n/10;m=n;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVHbboMwDH3vV1hIlZLWqAnZRVPGXqZ9xVpNFQ0dUuNWwAMa4tfHTKBTmZbExDk@x05MFh@zrO@dzQWhl21@LoVLT@ejVoKk9XFsJaW01GrlmguDTq5po5X1KdmuL6gGvy9IyEW7AB4DULuq/qD3HaTQ6sTgzFArXipsgyWms3Oln5SYoME7fDCPOPjDVDdcvo5rancIbGiNZoLRocjg63EqYNM3ZbLPfbmCcqwRbZu3ZNs8vbLdRwi3ZxOxIki4JyCGkgUdXMM6ZSf3Gariy51zcb2M3EzA6hexsF4HtoSxRdcHEGeaWhXiOzsL@2vY/xuuODz@sznuGP9tzV/hpWRKLqKlOSDwB@KXsC2rLfHzCcEjVMjt4fScZzcl7xZd/53lp/2x6uOT/wE)

Inputs integers \$n\$ and \$m\$.
Base-10 digitally rotates \$n\$ right \$m\$-times and returns it.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 47 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,m:m and f(n[-1]+n[:-1],m-1)or int(n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVDRasMwDHz3V@gtNlMgjssKgexH0jCyxtkKtRpsF1ZCvz2TEvowZHEncRJnzY/8cyO3rlN7HcLXOABhaAIMNMKkqStt/0Zdw4ChtOYW4UJZk1mzT/mToAVta4f/Em3Fr9pAsnZGbfKwybFGhwd8d0cULlEZ5X9nf85@FImz3HR22ybc7lEBp933RdHdi9O9Ph7OBcJOrSuMmsQk24Q40LfXV0/6tdyYRoGYTjnq/QfdpTcKxNlukWsFnsvXzNZI3OBzYGDtHOUEU7FQ454IS2CA8gOWJGSJnW/b1D8Ls/4B)

Inputs \$n\$ as a string and \$m\$ as an integer.
Returns rotated \$n\$ as an integer.

Answer (score 3):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), `-hr`, 11 bytes

```
÷(¿|")⑷⅍⑸⅀ℤ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASYA2f9rZWf//8O3KMK/fCIp4pG34oWN4pG44oWA4oSk//8xMAox/y1ocg)

### Explained

```
÷(¿|")⑷⅍⑸⅀ℤ
÷               # Split m into individual numbers
 (¿|")          # n times, shift the stack right
      ⑷⅍⑸      # turn each character into a string
           ⅀ℤ   # sum stack and convert to integer. `-hr` prints it as integer
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 66 bytes

```java
(n,x)->new Long((""+n+n).substring(x=(n=(""+n).length())-x%n,x+n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY8xT8MwEIX3/IpTpUo2Tay0QTCUdGBAQoKpI2Jw0yR1cM5WfC6pUH97MBGI1dPTvfvenV4nzzLrjh@T6q0ZCLowC09Ki8ZjRcqguNkmlZbOwatUCF8JgPUHrSpwJCnI2agj9GHH9jQobN/eQQ6t4zMK8Kiefi89PCPVbT2kf/pisN1BA@XEMB15tsP6E35MxhaLFa6QC@cPbr7KxpJhOftc6BpbOjHOs3EZksHi03b@tr84qnthPAkbYqSRNUJaqy9svSnSnPMobh3JbSK5IpK7jeHSu@I@hsvjauRxLf65a3KdvgE)

Comment: n=110 m=2 seems to output 11 instead of 101...

Comment: Why is all the function support code (like `import java.util.function.*;` and even the trailing semicolon) not included in the bytes count?

Comment: @Noodle9 The trailing semicolon isn't counted because it's a lambda. One way of writing it is to have `Lambda lambda = (x, y) -> x+y;`, and yes you have a semicolon. Another way of using a lambda is this: `f.acceptLambda((x, y) -> x+y);`. Do you see a semicolon after the lambda ? No, but the lambda is still the same! This is possible because the semicolon isn't part of the lambda, but part of the storage of the lambda in a variable. Regarding the imports, I invite you to read [the relevant meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10085/16236).

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Good catch, I fixed it at a cost of 7 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 11 bytes

```
(".@|.":)~-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/NZT0HGr0lKw063T/a/43NDJWSFMw5ILQRlDaGEqbcBkCSTNjcy5DA4gyAwOIMigFo8GqDQA)

#### How it works

Uses [@Bubbler's tacit trick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/173657/95594) for `(F x) G (H y) = (G~F)~H`.

```
(".@|.":)~-
          - negate y to shift right
(       )~  flip arguments, so ((-y) ".@|. (":x))
      ":    convert x to string
    |.      shift that by negated y
 ".@        and convert back to number
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Io](http://iolanguage.org/), 89 bytes

Uses a `reduce` trick to assign different lines of STDIN to variables.

```
File standardInput readLines reduce(a,b,a splitAt(-b asNumber)reverse join)asNumber print
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcgxCoAwDADA3VdkVFBQf@AiCOIfUpshorEkqd@vLm7H8V3KzCeBOUpEjYuk7KCEcWUh@xTzTjW2oUWwdLJPXncB0LZ8BdJG6SE1guNmaf6FpCxeytD31fgC)

## [Io](http://iolanguage.org/), 56 bytes

```
method(a,b,doString(a splitAt(-b asNumber)reverse join))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8z/n6ZgZasQ8z83tSQjP0UjUSdJJyU/uKQoMy9dI1GhuCAns8SxREM3SSGx2K80Nym1SLMotSy1qDhVISs/M09T83@ahpKhgYGSjpGmQgFQV0lO3n8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>44</s> 40 bytes

```ruby
->a,b{a.to_s.chars.rotate(-b).join.to_i}
```

-4 from Dingus.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y5RJ6k6Ua8kP75YLzkjsahYryi/JLEkVUM3SVMvKz8zDySVWfu/oLSkWCEt2tDIWMcwlguJZ4TCM0bhmSB4OmbG5gieAbIhBgbIhqBwUHlAEw1iubi4/gMA)

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 19 bytes

```ruby
->a,b{a.rotate(-b)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY5RCoMwEET/c4qFQlGIIWppoWBP0BtIkMTGNoVWceNHUc@eRqv1a98OszPbdurjqsxFF0lVL1lbW2l1EKlwdFajLUqJGrOc5HGS0ljQHyQrpCscZqDH9DQDX7ycL951/sHfcCHYSzb94LsHyCWzdYGsfMgWJz3Yn71gQgpKjLCDq0ELdQU3czcWCdn@Y1qWD@jBB4FPajqLUOXTIrYgDNmzNu@pxMBICHFf)

taking a list of digits

Comment: [-21 bytes](https://tio.run/##RY5RCoMwEET/c4qFQlGIIWppoWBP0BtIkMTGNoVWceNHUc@eRqv1a98OszPbdurjqsxFF0lVL1lbW2l1EKlwdFajLUqJGrOc5HGS0ljQHyQrpCscZqDH9DQDX7ycL951/sHfcCHYSzb94LsHyCWzdYGsfMgWJz3Yn71gQgpKjLCDq0ELdQU3czcWCdn@Y1qWD@jBB4FPajqLUOXTIrYgDNmzNu@pxMBICHFf "Ruby – Try It Online")--[Numeric input and output can be a list of digits](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18097/85110), which means you don't need any of the pre- or post-processing you included

Comment: That is fine by the rules, but I didn't want to do it. I will add your changes separately.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), (4?) 5 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

<sup>4 if we may accept a list of digits (remove the leading `D`).</sup>

```
DṙN}Ḍ
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/l4c6ZfrUPd/T8///f2MTUzNzC0sDQ6L@hMQA)**

#### How?

```
DṙN}Ḍ - Link: integer, n; integer, m
D     - convert to base ten
   }  - use m as the input of:
  N   -   negate
 ṙ    - rotate (n) left by (-m)
    Ḍ - convert from base ten
```

Comment: Is it standard now to allow a list of digits as input when the challenge asks for an integer? All I could find was [this sort-of-related proposed I/O default](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18097/16766), but it doesn't have the votes to be considered accepted yet.

Comment: Hmm, I just saw strings being used in answers and assumed that meant list input must be fine. I could take an integer and prefix with `D`.

Comment: Are strings allowed in place of integers by default?

Comment: ... It depends? That's what the linked meta answer proposes, and it hasn't been accepted yet. But then, if you have a full program that gets input from stdin, it's going to be reading a string in most languages. I don't see how to get around that. "Must convert the input string to integer" won't work: some languages (*cough*like mine*cough*) don't even have different types for strings and numbers. I noticed the string inputs in other answers too, and didn't like them, but wasn't sure what to say; and then yours stuck out a bit more, so I commented on it. Thanks for the edit. :)

Comment: @DLosc: The OP's notion of a "number" is apparently a sequence of digits, not a binary integer, because they didn't even specify anything about what base it should be in.  But it can't be base 2 (the natural base for computer integers) because they have digit values from 0 to 3.  So at least base 4?  With all this stuff about removing leading zeros in the result, it barely even makes sense for the result to be a fixed-width binary integer like C `int` either.  If this is the kind of thing you want to do with numbers in your program, keeping them as strings or lists makes the most sense.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <sup><s>42</s></sup> 40 bytes

```python
lambda x,r:int(x[(a:=-r%len(x)):]+x[:a])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcwxCoAgGEDhvVOEEPiTgWVUCJ2kGoySAjMRBzu90Wiu34NnHnfcmg3GBjnOQYlr3UTuieWndthPWPCxsoXaNfYAfCn9xMUCwdivS4zqhiFSA2SxNImwRNpIEOlYHwn9j@n/m8r3pQDhBQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-nl`, 34 bytes

```ruby
->m{($_*-~m*2)[~~/$/*m,~/$/].to_i}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYfLCoMwFAX3/YqLzaINJj5pV/ZHJIS2KBW8iZi4KDF@etMonGHmzMvrG/omsAe6C5GUbUjLa7ttGckoprsEt1oOPrQ057xOb9Vd8O75/jhYcYVpsQYSBQ2cHZE@BTwSY82dWUZ73L5F4RPwoTgVeVxkd1n99GQHrUxgavwD)

Takes \$n\$ from STDIN and \$m\$ as an argument. Concatenates \$n\$ \$2(m+1)\$ times, then from this string takes the substring of length \$d\$ (where \$d\$ is the number of digits in \$n\$) that begins \$m(d+1)\$ characters from the end. In the code, `$_` is \$n\$ and `~/$/` gives \$d\$.

#### Example

For \$n=123\$, \$m=2\$:

1. Concatenate \$n\$ \$2(m+1)=6\$ times: `123123123123123123`
2. Count back from the end \$m(d+1)=8\$ characters: `123123123123123123`
3. Take substring of length \$d=3\$: `123123123123123123`

Answer (score 2):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cjam/), <strike>10</strike> <strike>7</strike> 6 bytes

Saved 3 bytes by remembering that you can preform most array operations on strings.

-1 byte from @my pronoun is monicareinstate noting that `m>` takes arguments in either order.

```
rr~m>~
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/v6ioLteu7v9/QyNjBRMA)

Explanation:

```
rr       Read two string inputs
  ~      Parse m to number
   m>    Rotate n string right m times
     ~   Parse n to number to remove leading zeros
         (implicit) output
```

### Old version, 7 bytes:

```
q~\sm>~
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/v7AupjjXru7/f0MjYwUjAA)

Explanation:

```
q~        Take input as a string, evaluate to two numbers
  \       Swap order
   s      Convert n to string
    m>    Rotate n string right m times
      ~   Parse n to number to remove leading zeros
          (implicit) output
```

Comment: [6 bytes?](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/v6ioLteu7v9/QyNjBRMA "CJam – Try It Online")

Comment: Huh, for some reason I never knew you could take the arguments for `m>` (and probably many other functions) in either order.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 4 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319) ([SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS))

Anonymous tacit infix function. Takes string `n` as right argument and number `m` as left argument.

```apl
⍎-⍛⌽
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn//1Fvn@6j3tmPevb@T3vUNgHIfdTV/Kh3zaPeLYfWGz9qm/iob2pwkDOQDPHwDP5vmKZuaGSsrqDwqHeugrGhEZcRsoCRsSGXMbIAkMVlgq7FzNgcKARTwQUy0gDIg3JBBhoYqKNw4bIGCmABQ7i8gSGXAbqFQBWWlpYW6mABSwtLSwA)

`⍎` execute the result of

`-⍛` negating the left argument, then using that to

`⌽` cyclically rotate the right argument

Answer (score 2):

## (non-competing) [L=tn](https://github.com/Ghilt/Listen), 10

```
cα;θ2$cD=0
```

Explanation (in order of execution):

```
cα;         -  Turn first number into a list of digits
    2$c     -  Fetch second number as a number 
   θ        -  Shift list from first step by number from second step
       D=0  -  Drop while equals to zero
```

It prints result as a string.

Note: The language is in progress and I did add stuff to code golf this. So it is not a competing submission.

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 43 bytes

```
FromDigits@RotateRight[IntegerDigits@#,#2]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277360oP9clMz2zpNghKL8ksSQ1KDM9oyTaM68kNT21CCqjrKNsFKv2P6AoM69EwSE92tDIWMcwlguFb4TGN0bjmyDzdcyMzZH5BqjGGRigGofGRecDTTeI/f8fAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 29 bytes

```
,.+
$*_
+`(.*)(\d)_
$2$1
^0+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wX0dPm0tFK55LO0FDT0tTIyZFM55LxUjFkCvOQJvr/39DI2MdQy4QaQQmjcGkCZehjpmxOZehAUjSwAAkCSYgJFCFAQA) Link includes test cases. Takes input as `n,m`. Explanation:

```
,.+
$*_
```

Convert `m` to unary.

```
+`(.*)(\d)_
$2$1
```

Rotate `n` `m` times. This is O(m³) because of the way the regex backtracks trying to find a second match. Right-to-left matching, anchoring the match at the start, or rewriting the code to take input as `m,n` would reduce the time complexity (at a cost of a byte of course).

```
^0+
```

Delete leading zeros.

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 61 bytes

```
(n,m)=>{val s=n+""size;val(a,b)=n+""splitAt s-m%s;b++a toInt}
```

[Try it in Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/8jPaXDKbREuCSjrzyjAqKw)

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://www.php.net/), <strike>45</strike> 43 bytes

Saved 2 bytes, realized we can shorten the variable names.

```
<?=(int)(substr($s,-$n).substr($s,0,-$n))?>
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRoKBSbKtkaGCgZK2SZ2tkrWBvBxS31cjMK9HUKC5NKi4p0lAp1tFVydPUQ3ANwAKaQLX/gVq5jAA)

Explanation:

```
<?= ?>       Shorthand for <?php echo ;?>
  (int)      Typecast string to int, removes 0s from prefix
   substr()  substr(string,start,[length]), returns part of string, 
             if range go out of bounds, starts again from the opposite end.
             Basically returns part of from a 'circular' string.
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. I'm not sure that your code works. For inputs of `100` and `2`, the output should be `1`; your code outputs `10`.

Comment: Thank you! Fixed it. @Dingus

Comment: Nice work. I don't know PHP but it looks the input is hard-coded in the variables `$s` and `$n`? If so, that's [not allowed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8731/92901).

Comment: It's also supposed to loop rotating when `$n` is greater than the length of `$s`, which your code doesn't (fails for test case `123,4 => 312`)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 47 bytes

```javascript
(n,m,k=(e=n+'').length)=>+(e+e).substr(k-m%k,k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc1LDsIgGATgvadgY/oT6ANwAQu8S21oVSiYUnt9bGqjia27Sb7MzL2e6tgMt8eYTzK1OoGnPbUajPYky3DhjO/GK9ZnAoYYXMTnJY4D2Lw/WmpxaoKPwZnChQ5aYFzQCmOEyhLNGR22zFYWjO8oX5ULtqPiO72jp//L1ft26aIt8g9WP6iUkgvPqKRS6QU)

Answer (score 1):

## [V (vim)](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 11 bytes

```
Àñ$x0Pñó^0«
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v//3DD4Y0qFQYBhzce3hxncGj1//@GBgb/jQA)

```
Àñ    ñ       # (M-@)rg number of times
  $           # end of line
   x          # delete character (cut)
    0         # beginning of line
     P        # paste character
       ó      # (M-s)ubsitute 
        ^0«   # ^0\+
              # (implicitly) with nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 57 bytes

```hs
f n m=read(foldr(\_ y->last y:init y)(show n)[1..m])::Int
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY5Ba4MwGIbv/ooP2SGhaWeSsjUyex9spx2dlDAjyjQVzZiR/XcXmxQ85eF53@8ltRy/VdsuSwUaumxQskTVtS0H9HkBuz@3cjRg00Y37sForK@/oHFOD4euwGn6qs1SwwQW5gxiFMNuB7404ZVjAhtnvcOQnbf6Aap1wofwuI1mL5GaevVlVInjKOpkoyGDTvbvF@h/zIcZ3jTk4Rt/aCKWzPhlnyPKOKGEU4bJjRlhnAZ2CeOBj/cOeeLP5NZI3KGHxJ0F5SBZKeB9KglTQoiTC8RJCFwU0fIP)

```
f n m=            - function expecting two integers

foldr ... [1..m]  - folds `m` times..
      .. (show n)  - starting with `n` converted to string
      . (\_ y->last y:init y)  - moving the last element in head
read( ... )::Int  - convert the result to Int
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Excel/Google Sheets], 63 bytes

With n and m in columns a and b, and this formula in column c

```
=VALUE(RIGHT(A4, MOD(B4,LEN(A4)))&LEFT(A4,LEN(A4)-MOD(B4,LEN(A4
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: These should get you to 47: 1. Put `LEN(A1)` in `C1` and `MOD(B1,C1)` in `D1`. 2. Instead of `VALUE()`, use `--()` if you need a number.

Answer (score 1):

## SimpleTemplate 0.84, 106 bytes

This challenge really got my head spinning...

```
{@fnR N,T}{@forfrom Tto1}{@ifN matches"@(.+)(.)@"M}{@setN"#{M.2}#{M.1}"}{@/}{@/}{@set+N N,0}{@returnN}{@/}
```

This creates a function `R` that takes the `N`umber and the amount of `T`imes you want to swap the numbers around.

The way it works is by evaluating if the `N`umber matches a regular expression (`{@ifN matches"@(.+)(.)@"M}`) and storing the `M`atched parts.

Then, it reconstructs the number with the last digit at the beginning (`{@setN"#{M.2}#{M.1}"}`).

To remove leading zeroes, I've simply stored the sum of whatever is the `N`umber with 0, returning it after.

---

**Ungolfed:**

It is a lot easier to follow an ungolfed example:

```
{@fn rotate_n number, times}
    {@for i from times to 1}
        {@if number matches "@^(.+)(.)$@" matches}
            {@set number "#{matches.2}#{matches.1}"}
        {@/}
    {@/}
    {@set+ number number, 0}
    {@return number}
{@/}
```

The `i` is totally useless there, but removing it is a golfing step.

---

---

You can try this on: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/91d0d49d2f750022e21cc7b1c18e6beec55f9c8b

You can change the values on line 1071.

Answer (score 1):

## Golfscript - 28 bytes

```
~:a;`{1/)\+}a*1/{(~:b!}do b\
```

- input: `10450 4`
- output: `4501`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v84q0Tqh2lBfM0a7NlHLUL9ao84qSbE2JV8hKeb/f0MDE1MDBRMA)

**Explanation**

```
~:a;`                         # Parses the input "123 3" -> "123" on stack and a = 3
     {1/)\+}a*                # Pushes the last digit away and rejoins, repeat a times "123" -> "12" "3" -> "3" "12" -> "312" repeat
              1/{(~:b!}do b\  # Discard the leading elements until a non-zero element is found
```

There's room for improvement.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 3 bytes

```
ǔṅ⌊
```

[Try it Online](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLHlOG5heKMiiIsIiIsIjJcbjEwMCJd) or [Verify all the test cases](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#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)

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <sup>29</sup> 25 bytes

```
{.(y#a),(y:-(#a)!y)_a:$x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.bitbucket.io/k/#eJxLs6rW06hUTtTU0ai00tUAMhQrNeMTrVQqarm40qINjYytDWOhDCMYwxjGMAEzrM2MzcEMA6haAwOoWhgNZwD1GIAYlpaWFkAhAN03Hzw=-)

*¯4 thanks to @ovs*

Comment: `$` for ``10\`` and `.` for `10/` saves a couple bytes, and you can go a bit shorter by doing some arithmetic on the indices with `{a@ ... !n:#a:$x}`

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://www.php.net/), 89 bytes

```
list($n,$m)=explode(",",$argn);while($m--){$n=$n[-1].substr($n,0,-1);}echo ltrim($n,"0");
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcvNCgIhFEDhVwm5Cy9cQ9va0G5eImbRj6SgV1GjgejVs2ZzFh@c4ss4nsq/MbQugQkSTm4tMd@dFCQILvXBaF8@RCchKYVv4An4rMyyb89r63XbNCmD9uNuPu9iryFtKLRAO4bRmg7fXHrI3Iaafw)

Explanation: A PHP answer that works by looping m times through the given string n moving the last character of n to the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 18 bytes

```
{.y{(*|x):':x}/$x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs6rWq6zW0Kqp0LRSt6qo1VepqOXiSos2NDKOVVc0AbJMoLShgSGYxQUAeOYM6w==)

Right rotate inspired by @chrispsn.

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com), <s>76</s> 70 bytes

```
f(n,m)=mod(n,t)10^d/t+floor(n/t)
d=floor(log(n+0^n))+1
t=10^{mod(m,d)}
```

[Try it on Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rwae2ifnsu)

Port of R answer.

*-6 bytes thanks to Aiden Chow*

Answer (score 0):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 14 bytes

```
~\`\{1/)\+}\*~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/vy4mIabaUF8zRrs2Rqvu/39DI2MFQwA)

```
~              # Puts n and m on top of the stack as integers
 \`\           # Parses n to string
    {1/)\+}    # This block goes to the top of the stack without being executed
           \*  # Executes previous block m times
             ~ # Parses the answer from string to integer, this removes the leading zeroes
```

What the block does:

```
     1/        # Parses the string to an array of strings
       )\      # Separates the last digit and puts it in the begining
         +     # Concatenates them again
```

Comment: The last backslash is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org), 19 bytes

```factor
[ neg rotate dec> ]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70sLTG5JL9owc2PocGefu5WCrmJJRkKxamFpal5yanFeqkVJUWJxWBRvYLEouLUIoXE4uL85GKFgqLUkpLKgqLMvBIFay6uai4FIKhWUDI0MlZSMFSoReEbofGN0fgmSHwlBTNjcyS-AapxBgaoxqFx0fkg0w0QfEtLSwuIgtqlpSVpuhaboxXyUtMVivJLEktSFVJSk-0UYiEya9MgXrXLTSxQ0IOILVgAoQE)

Answer (score 0):

## Lua 5.1 (58 bytes)

```
n=n..""for _=1,m do n=n:sub(-1)..n:sub(1,-2)end print(n*1)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ẒN
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSVFMSVCOSU5OCZjb2RlPSVFMSVCQSU5Mk4mZm9vdGVyPSZpbnB1dD0xMjMlMkMlMjAxJTIwJTIwJTIwJTIwJTNEJTNFJTIwMzEyJTBBMTIzJTJDJTIwMiUyMCUyMCUyMCUyMCUzRCUzRSUyMDIzMSUwQTEyMyUyQyUyMDMlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlM0QlM0UlMjAxMjMlMEExMjMlMkMlMjA0JTIwJTIwJTIwJTIwJTNEJTNFJTIwMzEyJTBBMSUyQyUyMDYzNyUyMCUyMCUyMCUyMCUzRCUzRSUyMDElMEExMCUyQyUyMDElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlM0QlM0UlMjAxJTBBMTAwJTJDJTIwMiUyMCUyMCUyMCUyMCUzRCUzRSUyMDElMEExMCUyQyUyMDIlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlM0QlM0UlMjAxMCUyMCUwQTExMCUyQyUyMDIlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlM0QlM0UlMjAxMDElMEExMjMlMkMlMjAwJTIwJTIwJTIwJTIwJTNEJTNFJTIwMTIzJTBBOTk5OCUyQyUyMDIlMjAlMjAlMjAlM0QlM0UlMjA5ODk5JmZsYWdzPUM=)

##### Explanation

```python
    # Implicit input
Ẓ   # Rotate right that many times
 N  # Convert to integer to remove leading zeros
    # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

### awk

```
awk '($++NF=(__=$++_)*(_!_)^((__=length(__))-$(_+_)%__)%((_!_)^__-_--))' FS=,
```

---

```
123 1 => 312 312
123 2 => 231 231
123 3 => 123 123
123 4 => 312 312
1 637 => 1 1
10 1 => 1 1
100 2 => 1 1
10 2 => 10  10
110 2 => 101 101
123 0 => 123 123
9998 2 => 9899 9899
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Uiua](https://www.uiua.org), 6 bytes

```
⍜⊙°⋕↻¯
```

[Test pad](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_8_0__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)

Takes the amount to rotate on top of the stack.